# how does image in a rich text html editor get saved and stored?

Tags: javascript, quill

I am considering using [quill.js](https://quilljs.com/) as a HTML editor on my page. I see it is possible to add a image (from your computer) to the HTML Editor. But where does this get saved when I save the form?
Do I need to save it a as a separate file? Will it be saved as a BLOB in DB? Or any other way?

Comment: This seems like something you'd find more easily in the libraries documentation.

Comment: It will be saved in your database along with other texts in base64 format, i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [the source of the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aux8.png) ([using the playgrund](https://codepen.io/quill/pen/KzZqZx)) inside the editor, you can see that the image data is converted to a [`data:URI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) with base64 encoding.

If you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690641/img-url-to-dataurl-using-javascript) you will get an idea of how they are converted.

Using this makes it easy to store pictures or other binary data inside any site without referring to other sources.