# HTML embed PDF , Set Content from Buffer

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed

I have an html embed tag and want to show a pdf inside. This works with src, from a file. But rather from a File I want to load the content from the memory. So I get back the pdf data from a rest api in buffer and want to feed this into the embed tags. Is this possible?
this is some example code

```
<div id ="pdfView">
    <embed class="form-control" src="some/path/file.pdf" id="pdf"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

A clunky way would be to download a temporary file on the server then update the file name used in the `src`. I haven't tested but it seems like it should work.

Another way is with a data tag. You need to Base64 encode the PDF contents and then produce a `src` tag using [the data URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397).

Example:

```
<embed class="form-control" src="data:application/pdf;base64,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" id="pdf"/>
```

The above is the Base64 encoded data of [this minimal PDF example](https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0004.html). You can't give it a filename like this, though, and might see something weird in its place.

If you need a guide on Base64 encoding that's possibly out of scope but plenty of solutions on here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript).

Comment: works for that question. But I cannot straight encode base64 as I get non Latin1 error. with window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response)) I get a white pdf....

Comment: You could try the trick mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41445058/2060441

Comment: Works on Chrome, but fails in Edge and IE11

Comment: Exactly. The data URL scheme is there for you. Great!