# How to display image from database using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js, axios

How can i display my image which the image call from database but only return alot question mark... see here >>>
[image: Resdata]

If i direct call the API using the link it come out it result:

```
{"success":false,"message":"No token provided"}
```

```
async getImage(){
const res = await MemberService.getmemberprofileimage('1667546872110-agape-1667546868823.jpeg').then(function(response){
        return response;
      })
      if(res.status == 200){
        if(res.data.success != false){
          this.gImage = res.data;
          console.log('Res:', res);
        }
      }
    }
```

ReturnData:

[image: ReturnData]

Comment: your response seems to be binary data. One way could be converting that to base64 data and pass it to an `img` element's `src`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert binary data to base64 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982712/convert-binary-data-to-base64-with-javascript)

Comment: @GrafiCode the code change to base64 but I cant show on <img> tag

Comment: @Meow Could you share the full URL get an image or full data from the response?

Comment: @ChuongTran hi, I update the full data you can check the ReturnData image

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to convert the binary data to base64 data.

```
res.end(res.data.toString('base64'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show binary data on an `img` tag you could use `URL.createObjectURL` in your FE code to display the image

```
const imageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
<img src=`${imageSrc}` />
```