# Intervention Image broken in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, intervention

I'm trying to create an image on the fly without saving and sending to the Vue but I can't get to display.

in Laravel

```
$img = Image::make('image-path')->resize(400, 400);
        $img->text('name', 205, 138, function($font) {
            $font->file('fonts/BostonHeavy.woff');
            $font->size(42);
            $font->color('#ffffff');
            $font->align('center');
            $font->valign('top');
        });
            return $img->response('jpg');
```

in Vue

```
data () {
    return {
      image: null
    }
  },

  methods: {

  async fetchData (param) {

      this.image = await this.$axios.$get(`image`)
  }
}
```

in template

```
{{image}}
or
<img :src="image" />
```

always displays broken, though testing on Postman it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are putting a bunch of binary data into your img's src attribute, which does not work.

You need to convert the image to a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) as described here [How can I convert image binary from API call to data URI in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394721/how-can-i-convert-image-binary-from-api-call-to-data-uri-in-javascript)

If your endpoint does not need authentication (or any other special headers or payloads) you could also directly put the link to the image-generating endpoint directly into your img's src attribute. E.g. if your image is generated at `/api/image` then just simply put `<img src="/api/image" />`.