# How to use Javascript to automatically save the images on the website with Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Method 1.

-- use the iframe.

1. Create an iframe, when pressing the save button.
2. set the "src" property to a url of an image on the website.
3. invoke the iframe.document.execommand. //useless, it seems the execommand is only for IE.

Method 2.

-- use a canvas

1. Create a canvas
2. Draw the image into the canvas.
3. invoke `toDataURL` // Security Error

**manifest.js:**

```
{
  "name" : "...",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : ".....",
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["http://domain/p/*"],
    "js" : ["i.js"],
    "css" : ["i.css"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.domain.com/*"
  ]
}
```

Is there any other way to handle the problem?

Comment: I'm using method 2 (with canvas) - why do you have security error?

Comment: hi @hamczu , the Images have not the same domain as the website. Maybe it is the reason .

Comment: Do you have this domain in the manifest permissions? Maybe you can paste your code here or on jsFiddle so we would have some base to work on. Another solution: catch all image urls requests with chrome.webRequest API

Comment: @hamczu i'll add the manifest file as soon as i get home and try the chrome.webRequest api...

Comment: `execCommand` is supported by Chrome. In fact, it's the recommended method of [copying and pasting](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) for extensions.

Comment: @Alasdair In IE theres a save (or something like that) execCommand that will cause a save dialog to come up for the current document, there is no such functionality in Chrome (last time I checked anywayz).

Comment: Problem I have with method 2 is your not actually saving the image but a copy of it.  So if its as a jpeg and you re save it as a jpeg then it was first decompressed and your actually saving a copy that is re compressed and this may cause more degradation, or if you save it as a png then the file size would likely increase.  The only way I could think of to truly save the image is to re get it using xhr and save that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/getting-blob-data-from-xhr-request ...if your hardcore then use webRequest to block images and put them in the page yourself.

Comment: What security error is it showing? is is unsafe_eval?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question, but since then `chrome.downloads` API became a thing.

It's sufficient to extract URLs of all the images you're interested in, and pass them to [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download). Please note that you may need to set a referrer in some rare cases.