# Convert blob URL to normal URL

Tags: javascript, url, blob

My page generates a URL like this: `"blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8383/568233a1-8b13-48b3-84d5-cca045ae384f"` How can I convert it to a normal address?

I'm using it as an `<img>`'s `src` attribute.

Comment: even after decoding the URL, it's still a `localhost` link. Find out its public link instead. (which CDN are you using?)

Comment: I am wishing to use javascript.

Comment: Use the [stackvoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) .. and [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent) Your real problem will be how to make it independent of environment you deploy your code in

Comment: Is there a way to find the public URL from the blob adress. Thhis is the only value I have.

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/q/948738/78897

Comment: https://codepen.io/vidhill/pen/bNPEmX

Comment: just to example why we cannot directly open or XHR to video src blob:xxxx.com/xxxx .This blob is created by URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource). Here is the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#examples)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A URL that was created from a JavaScript `Blob` can not be converted to a "normal" URL.

A `blob:` URL does not refer to data the exists on the server, it refers to data that your browser currently has in memory, for the current page. It will not be available on other pages, it will not be available in other browsers, and it will not be available from other computers.

Therefore it does not make sense, in general, to convert a `Blob` URL to a "normal" URL. If you wanted an ordinary URL, you would have to send the data from the browser to a server and have the server make it available like an ordinary file.

It is possible convert a `blob:` URL into a `data:` URL, at least in Chrome. You can use an AJAX request to "fetch" the data from the `blob:` URL (even though it's really just pulling it out of your browser's memory, not making an HTTP request).

Here's an example:

```js
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], { type: 'text/plain' });
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function() {
   var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;

   var reader = new FileReader;

   reader.onload = function() {
     var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;
     window.location = blobAsDataUrl;
   };

   reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);
};

xhr.open('GET', blobUrl);
xhr.send();
```

`data:` URLs are probably not what you mean by "normal" and can be problematically large. However they do work like normal URLs in that they can be shared; they're not specific to the current browser or session.

Comment: If blob urls don't point to server data, then how come Youtube videos' src url look like:

src="blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/44f26667-03f1-4978-9eed-af0cbf11dd67"

(in Chrome)

Comment: @bhh1988 That's a very interesting find. I'm not sure what's going on there. If I try to retrieve their src blob URL using an XMLHttpRequest, as described in this post, no content is returned. My guess is that either (a) they generated any empty Blob URL to use as a placeholder while feeding in data from another source or (b) the Blob somehow acts as a proxy for encrypted data (via HTML5 Encrypted Media Extensions). However, I'm not sure how either of these could actually be done in practice.

Comment: @bhh1988 It looks like the [media source extensions spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) allows blob URLs to be created for media streams being managed by JavaScript. These do not correspond to static data like the blob URLs discussed in this post, hence the difference in behavior, but they still refer to local information, not directly to data on a server.

Comment: Hmm, sounds right. It's confusing because the url looks real and intentful, but if it's just a placeholder it shouldn't matter what the value of src is.

Comment: I get a `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/plain;base64,...` error. I get the data, but the `window.location` it is not allowed...

Comment: I know this question is old, but you can use `puppeteer` to capture the true media calls in-flight and then assemble it's chunks to a file. Takes a bit of byte and stream manipulation, but it's doable.

Comment: I am using this in Electron.js environment. worked for me too.

Comment: Each blob has to be created from something. So it should be possible to examine javascript that is launched on page load to see from what it generates.

Comment: @loretoparisi that has been disabled by browsers for security purposes.

Comment: any solution? This solution not work to me

Answer (score 20):

another way to create a data url from blob url may be using canvas.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0) // i assume that img.src is your blob url
var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("your prefer type", your prefer quality)
```

as what i saw in mdn, canvas.toDataURL is supported well by browsers. (except ie<9, always ie<9)

---

**Demo**:

```js
let blobToImage=(binaryUrl) => {
  var canvas=document.createElement("canvas")
  var img=document.createElement('img');
  img.src=binaryUrl;
  var context=canvas.getContext("2d")
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}

let blobUrl = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014__340.jpg";
let imgUrl = blobToImage(blobUrl);
console.log(blobUrl);
console.log(imgUrl);
```

Comment: Note that this of course applies only for image data, and some metadata might be lost!

Comment: Doing this creates a link but if you follow it you only get a black box.

Comment: @Antfish, That shouldn't happen isn't it?

Answer (score 17):

For those who came here looking for a way to download a blob url video / audio, [this answer worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901942/how-do-we-download-a-blob-url-video?answertab=votes#tab-top) for me. In short, you would need to find an *.m3u8 file on the desired web page through **Chrome** -> **Network tab** and paste it into a **VLC player**.

Another guide shows you how to [save a stream with the VLC Player](https://www.zachpoff.com/resources/stream-recording-with-vlc/).

---

**UPDATE:**

An alternative way of downloading the videos from a blob url is by using the mass downloader and joining the files together.

**Download Videos Part**

1. Open network tab in chrome dev tools

[image]

2. Reload the webpage
3. Filter .m3u8 files

[image]

4. Look through all filtered files and find the playlist of the '.ts' files. It should look something like this:

[image]

5. You need to extract those links somehow. Either download and edit the file manually OR use any other method you like. As you can see, those links are very similar, the only thing that differs is the serial number of the video: 's-**0**-v1-a1.ts', 's-**1**-v1-a1.ts' etc.

   https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-0-v1-a1.ts

   https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-1-v1-a1.ts

   [https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-2-v1-a1.ts](https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-2-v1-a1.ts%E2%80%A8)

and so on up to the last link in the .m3u8 playlist file. These .ts files are actually your video. You need to download all of them.

6. For bulk downloading I prefer using the Simple Mass Downloader extension for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-mass-downloader/abdkkegmcbiomijcbdaodaflgehfffed)
7. If you opt in for the Simple Mass Downloader, you need to:

   a. Select a Pattern URL

[image]

b. Enter your link in the address field with only one modification: that part of the link that is changing for each next video needs to be replaced with the pattern in square brackets [0:400] where 0 is the first file name and 400 is the last one. So your link should look something like this [https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-[0:400]-v1-a1.ts](https://some-website.net/del/8cf.m3u8/s-%5B0:400%5D-v1-a1.ts).

Afterwards hit the Import button to add these links into the Download List of Mass Downloader.

[image]

c. The next action may ask you for the destination folder for EACH video you download. So it is highly recommended to specify the default download folder in Chrome Settings and disable the Select Destination option in Chrome Settings as well. This will save you a lot of time! Additionally you may want you specify the folder where these files will go to:

[image]

c1. Click on Select All checkbox to select all files from the Download List.

[image]

c2. Click on the Download button in the bottom right corner of the SMD extension window. It will take you to next tab to start downloading

[image]

c3. Hit Start selected. This will download all vids automatically into the download folder.

[image]

That is it! Simply wait till all files are downloaded and you can watch them via the VLC Player or any other player that supports the .ts format. However, if you want to have one video instead of those you have downloaded, you need to join all these mini-videos together

**Joining Videos Part**

Since I am working on Mac, I am not aware of how you would do this on Windows. If you are the Windows user and you want to merge the videos, feel free to google for the windows solution. The next steps are applicable for Mac only.

1. Open Terminal in the folder you want the new video to be saved in
2. Type: `cat` and hit `space`
3. Open the folder where you downloaded your `.ts` video. Select all `.ts` videos that you want to join (use your mouse or `cmd+A`)
4. Drag and drop them into the terminal
5. Hit `space`
6. Hit `>`
7. Hit `Space`
8. Type the name of the new video, e.g. `my_new_video.ts`. Please note that the format has to be the same as in the original videos, otherwise it will take long time to convert and even may fail!
9. Hit `Enter`. Wait for the terminal to finish the joining process and enjoy watching your video!

Comment: This work*ed* ... until clever HTML/JS gurus started avoiding `*.m3u8` altogether. Bummer!

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150333/html5-javascript-dataurl-to-blob-blob-to-dataurl) and wanted to reference it as it appear much cleaner than the accepted answer:

```js
function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: what is blob? Does it equal to "blob:https:/...."???

Answer (score -3):

I'm very late to the party.

If you want to download the content you can simply use `fetch` now

```
fetch(blobURL)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => /*do what you want with the blob here*/)
```

Comment: I've been trying to use your code (with some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021822/1035977), but, apparently, `fetch()` _cannot_ get a `blob:https://example.com/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000` URL. I'm investigating further...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn Have you found any solution?

Comment: did you test it's first before answer here?

Answer (score -4):

Here the solution:

```
        let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
        let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const blobF = await fetch(videoURL).then(res => res.blob())
```

Comment: about type mime is dont `video/mp4` and correct is `octet/stream`.

Comment: did you test it's first before answer here?

Answer (score -6):

As the previous answer have said, there is no way to decode it back to url, even when you try to see it from the chrome devtools panel, the url may be still encoded as blob.

However, it's possible to get the data, another way to obtain the data is to put it into an anchor and directly download it.

```
<a href="blob:http://example.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" download>download</a>
```

Insert this to the page containing blob url and click the button, you get the content.

Another way is to intercept the ajax call via a proxy server, then you could view the true image url.

Comment: <a href="blob:http://example.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" download="abc.txt">download</a>. It should work. When it will hit the href, it will rename the blob to abc.txt & download

Comment: Why the downvotes? have you actually tried what I said?

Comment: I have not downvoted. I came here. And, I thought it will work. I am in support of this a littlebit

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, but this certainly sounds a straightforward way. (With that said, I always get `Failed - Network error` in Chrome 83.0.4103.97 on Linux.)

Comment: Quite interesting. I've opened DevTools and added a bit of HTML with that link. It certainly does 'something': it shows up on the page, sure, and you can click to download it — but, like @toraritte said, I also get a `Failed - Network error`.