# How do I get the src of an audio recording?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, src

I am trying to get the blob url src from the audio control as seen from this Inspect Element snippet:

```
<audio controls="" src="blob:http%3A//icubs.org.uk/ef44814c-3eed-44a3-a085-f56ab8f34903" id="audio"></audio>
```

Does anyone know the best way to get this? Is it possible to get it using document.GetElementByID?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple DOM extraction and string parsing? Have you attempted anything yet? Read any documentation? Followed any tutorials? Which book are you following?

Comment: Hello @LightnessRacesinOrbit, sorry if the question was abit vague. I have been following this tutorial: https://subinsb.com/html5-record-mic-voice . However, I was trying to modify it slightly, by sending the blob url of the recorded audio via email using php (the php part is done already). The problem is that I can't get the blob url, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Like `document.getElementById("audio").src`?
[Convert blob URL to normal URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url)

Comment: hello @user3700591, I tried document.getElementById("audio").src but it also gave me the webpage url.