# How can i convert blob url to image string

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to save an image in aws bucket I get this url when I upload image from file in JSP page

```
 blob:http%3A//localhost/7555f111-bb1e-4d3d-90c6-0bb14875e25a
```

I have this code:

```
public String uploadImageToS3(String uri,String image)
{
   try{

     File file = createFileForS3(image);
        S3StreamUpload s3 =new S3StreamUpload();
        String result = s3.fileUploader("rosh-haayin-images",uri,file.getAbsolutePath());
        if(result.equals("unsuccess"))
        {
         status="-1";
        }
           System.out.println(result);

       } catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           status="-1";
       }
return status;

}
```

I want to use that src to get the image or file for use it in the fanctioin How can i convert it to image string or to file ?

Comment: try to be clearer. Here I see an absolute path where the ":" is just encoded. Exactly, what do you want  to get? Make an example.

Comment: i ediit the question Maybe now you  can help me

Comment: please check this url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url` seems like same case to me

Comment: i didnt understand that answer have you try it?