# Why can't I set image source to blob from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, blob

I am trying to load an image from file using Javascript LoadImage library (https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image).

The load method returns me an image object with its `src` set to some blob object:

`<img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3577/902d4e78-2e3e-467c-99ce-6683db24996e" width="960" height="540">`

If I append this element to DOM, it's displayed nicely. However, for my need, I just need the image data, not the DOM object. I need to take that data and set another, existing element's `src` to that. So, just like any sane person would do, I get the returned object's `src` (`blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3577/902d4e78-2e3e-467c-99ce-6683db24996e`), get a reference to my existing image DOM object (named `img` below), and using jQuery, set its src:

`img.attr('src', src);`

This results in my existing image object becoming:

`<img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3577/902d4e78-2e3e-467c-99ce-6683db24996e">`.

Yes, exactly the same (expect explicit `width` and `height` attributes, which I also tried to add, which changed absolutely nothing). But instead of the image, my existing tag now displays a broken image:

[image]

Why and how when image tags with the same `src`, one can display the image and the other cannot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url

Comment: @Malk it says blobs can't be shared between computers/networks/browsers etc, which is stating the obvious. however, my case is about two DOM elements within the same window.

Comment: Is the second DOM element in the exact same DOM as the first one? That is, are you trying to carry the blobs across page loads or something?

Comment: @duskwuff as I've clearly stated in the question, I'm in the same DOM they are even executed consequently in the same script block. there is no page load etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely due to the LoadImage library calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` in order to release the allocated image.

Try to [specify](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#options) the `noRevoke` option.

Comment: That was it. The default value is `false`, confusing users into that the URL is reusable.