# WebRTC Local Video

Tags: video, webrtc

When we use `getUserMedia` to get local video and attach to a video element the video element looks like this :

```
<video src="blob:https%3A//<domainName>%3A8443/5b1c2e58-b2a2-445a-82d6-9819572bcf30" autoplay=""></video>
```

In the `src` attribute, we can see that video element is getting the stream using `https`. Does that mean this video element is getting stream through the internet(like a remote stream is received) or `video` tag is smart enough to know whether this stream is coming from local camera and doesnot go to the internet.

Comment: https just means that the https protocol is used, it's a protocol for transferring (hyper)text and the s is for secure. It has nothing to do with internet or remote streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `blob` URI. The video tag retrieves a `blob` object stored in the memory of your browser (Chrome). It does not retrieve it directly from Internet.

However, before being in memory of your browser, it could be retrieved from a distant peer (e.g. `PeerConnection` in WebRTC), from a server (`XHR`, Ajax, etc.) through the network, or from your browser itself (`getUserMedia`, file object).

Comment: Thanks for that head up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url this answer was also helpful