# Get video direct url or file using blob:https://example

Tags: javascript, html, url, video, blob

So I am working on a service to universally download videos, I search for the

```
<video src="https://example.com/image/example"></video>
```

tag and get the src url in order to download the video. The problem rises when there is a 'blob:' in front of the url. That link points to no video source and I have no knowledge on how to retrieve the video.

Anything could be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How do we download a blob url video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901942/how-do-we-download-a-blob-url-video).

Comment: why would the link be a `blob:` unless you created a Blob, and used the `URL.createObjectURL` to create a blob uri? and if you did that, then you'd have access to the blob

Comment: The blob wasn't created by me, take vimeo for example their video sources are in blob form. I want to retrieve links to their videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, when a video as its `src` pointing to a blobURI (`blob://..`), it is not a Blob that is at the other end of the URI, but a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource).

You won't be able to retrieve the source of this data from your extension from this blobURI alone.

You'd have to check where the ArrayBuffers that do populate this MediaSource are coming from, but this is a way too broad subject for here.