# How to download a chrome extension blob video that has the source URL like this blob:chrome-extension://...?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is a video which I am viewing via an extension installed via Google Chrome store. When I open the video and inspect element, it has the following tag

```
<video controls="" preload="auto" src="blob:chrome-extension://olkpikmlhoaojbbmmpejnimiglejmboe/76df79f4-8d46-40e0-842f-6594a0b2c770" autoplay=""></video>
```

How do I download this video as mp4 or something else? There is no download button.

Comment: Check the link below, it may help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901942/how-do-we-download-a-blob-url-video

Comment: @YaswanthGupta no that works only for blobs from websites. This is a blob via an extension, meaning there is no external link.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's called "Downloader for Instagram™ (+ Upload photo)". It has a page where you can view live videos. These live videos have the src with the blob

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry for the delayed reply. After you install the extension, go to any instagram Profile. On the top right, you can see 3 extra icons. One is a phone icon(browse insta like on a phone), one is Download All button. There is another button which opens an extension page "stories.html" This is where you can view the live blob videos

Comment: Apparently there's no way because the extension plays the videos via MediaSource API and so there's no single data stream to save. Instead there are many DASH chunks that Chrome plays automatically without muxing to a single file. If I remember correctly, FFMPEG command line tool can stitch such video directly from an URL that points to `.mpd` video descriptor so look for the examples.