# blob file: Not accessible with link

Tags: html, blob

There is a big picture in this link https://www.sunday-webry.com/viewer.php?chapter_id=91141, the url of which can be found with inspector, looks like `blob:https://www.sunday-webry.com/1dfc33a7-cb4c-44f9-8642-df87bfc91fd5`. (blob links are only available in individual browser instances)

However, this `blob` link is unaccessible. The browser complains:

> ### Your file couldn’t be accessed
>
> It may have been moved, edited or deleted.
>
> `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`blob` link is sometimes accessible with link, see the `blob` image links found in https://viewer.ganganonline.com/manga/?chapterId=39373.

There should be some way to access the first `blob` image by link directly like the second one - but how to achieve that?

Comment: I guess this should be a duplicate, but I can't find one.

Comment: Or - maybe the `sunday` site remove the `blob` image links right after the browser has loaded the picture? So there is no way to get it.

Comment: Related maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `blob` link is only accessible **once**. And after it was read, the link is destroyed so that future operations become impossible.