# Record voice JS and send it to server

Tags: javascript, record

I am working for my exam at University and I need a help. I want to implement voice recording to web browser to record voice and then to  send it server for voice recognition. I have found this voice recording JS which can record voice and then  download it to PC as .wav file. I want to modify thi recorder to send this wav file not to PC but to server. Can you help me with this one?? Also I need to explain source code of this JS, because I am newe in JS. Thanks a lot guys.

Source code of recorder which I want to modify is there: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: See the `$.ajax()` and `XMLHttpRequest ` answers for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014638/recorderjs-uploading-recorded-blob-via-ajax)

Answer (score 3):

```
rec.exportWAV([callback][, type])
```

On the callback you must do the ajax request and upload the blob into the server.

```
rec.exportWAV(function(blob){
  // Send the blob to your server using ajax.
});
```

> BLOB = Binary Large Object.

The blob is a binary representation of your data(in this case the wav file).

Hope it helps.