# Convert blob to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a snippet for the code that I want to do `Blob` to `Base64` string:

This commented part works and when the URL generated by this is set to img src it displays the image:

```
var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
//var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
//var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
//console.log("image source=" + source);
                        
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
console.log(event.target.result)
}; // data url!
var source = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

The problem is with the lower code, the source variable generated is null

**Update:**

Is there an easier way to do this with JQuery to be able to create Base64 String from the Blob file as in the code above?

Comment: use `btoa` to convert bytes directly to base64; not sure what's up with the intermediate data urls in the answers.

Answer (score 517, accepted):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
  var base64data = reader.result;                
  console.log(base64data);
}
```

Form the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) `readAsDataURL` encodes to base64

As an `await`able function:

```
function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

> Note: The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove data:*/*;base64, from the result.

Comment: The output String doesn't seem to look like base64?

Comment: @xybrek If you print read.result, you will see base64 in the string itself.

Comment: But, Concern is how to get just Base64 String from that instead of those other tags, 
e.g. I am getting

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAKoWlDQ…ApOxJ4m+EDQbZE3wR+j7XSz2unTElvZ+s/1Vw/8B6sw4fipgOycAAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

but I want just : `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAKoWlDQ…ApOxJ4m+EDQbZE3wR+j7XSz2unTElvZ+s/1Vw/8B6sw4fipgOycAAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

Comment: console.log( base64data.substr(base64data.indexOf(',')+1) );

Comment: `onloadend` should come before `readAsDataURL` just in case something weird happens and it finishes loading before it reaches the next line of code. Obviously this would never happen but it's still good practice.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it appends none-base64 characters to the front of the string.

Comment: combined with https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901662/2860309 for reading from a blob url, this really helped!

Comment: @3ocene that can't happen. JavaScript is single-threaded, nothing weird can happen in the while.

Comment: @CristianTraìna `readAsDataURL` is a function call, and could, therefore, complete the entire load (including calling the event listeners) before the function returns. This is not how the function is implemented in every environment I know of, but JavaScript being single-threaded doesn't have anything to do with it. Furthermore, all it takes is for some junior developer to come along and unwittingly add an await statement or something in there, and suddenly you have a bug that is incredibly difficult to troubleshoot. As I said, "obviously this would never happen but it's still good practice."

Comment: @JoshuaSmith Yeah; I dunno, I mean, [you could just use `btoa(await blob.text())` and skip all this extra strangeness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72437954/616460). Maybe btoa wasn't around in 2013?

Comment: @3ocene No, it can't. The [File API spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsDataURL) defines [read ops](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readOperation); and `loadend` is *never* fired directly, as all paths to `loadend` [queue the event task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) on the [file reading task source](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blobreader-task-source), whose [implied event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#implied-event-loop) is the same one that's [executing the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72420662).

Comment: I.e. it will never fire "between lines of code"; the only opportunities it has is either during async awaits, or after the script has been fully executed. Also, on a higher level, W3C went to great lengths to build determinism into the web specs; and if it wasn't there in this case, most things just... wouldn't work -- in particular, API objects that begin firing events as soon as they are constructed would be essentially unusable.

Comment: this is `function blobToDataUrl`

Answer (score 57):

There is a pure JavaScript way that is not depended on any stacks:

```js
const blobToBase64 = blob => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
  });
};
```

For using this helper function you should set a callback, example:

```js
blobToBase64(blobData).then(res => {
  // do what you wanna do
  console.log(res); // res is base64 now
});
```

---

I write this helper function for my problem on React Native project, I wanted to download an image and then store it as a cached image:

```js
fetch(imageAddressAsStringValue)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blobToBase64)
  .then(finalResult => { 
    storeOnMyLocalDatabase(finalResult);
  });
```

Answer (score 54):

this worked for me:

```
var blobToBase64 = function(blob, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataUrl = reader.result;
        var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
        callback(base64);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
};
```

Comment: What is the argument `cb`?

Comment: @FellowStranger commonly callback, used like blobToBase64(myBlob, function(base64String) {/*use the base64String*/}), because it's async

Comment: @yeahdixon, Seems I need your help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192069/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-referenceerror-blob-is-not-defined

Comment: How do you wait for the execution? I always get undefined

Comment: the callback is meant to be a function that gets passed that fires when complete

Comment: i got the error "edit:1 Not allowed to load local resource: blob". Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 11):

```
var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audio.src = audioURL;

var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function () {
     base64data = reader.result;
     console.log(base64data);
}
```

Comment: Nice, @Vemonus because FileReader expose into result attribute as base64, works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

```
function bufferToBinaryString(arrayBuffer){
    return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
}
(async () => console.log(btoa(bufferToBinaryString(await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer()))))();
```

or

```
function bufferToBinaryString(arrayBuffer){
    return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
}
new Response(blob).arrayBuffer().then(arr_buf => console.log(btoa(bufferToBinaryString(arr_buf)))))
```

see [Response's constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response#Syntax), you can turn `[blob, buffer source form data, readable stream, etc.]` into [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods), which can then be turned into `[json, text, array buffer, blob]` with async method/callbacks.

edit: as @Ralph mentioned, turning everything into utf-8 string causes problems (unfortunately Response API doesn't provide a way converting to binary string), so [array buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) is use as intermediate instead, which requires two more steps (converting it to byte array THEN to binary string), if you insist on using native `btoa` method.

Comment: .text() decodes using UTF8, what happens if the response has binary code?
I believe this will fail for non text data

Comment: I see your point, amended the answer (it becomes quite lengthy though). At this point it would be better to not insist on `btoa`

Answer (score 7):

```js
async function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}

let blob = null; // <= your blob object goes here

blobToBase64(blob)
  .then(base64String => console.log(base64String));
```

See also:

- https://gist.github.com/moosetraveller/723987931308c9ec63725c14cdcbc3e7

Answer (score 7):

The answer from [@Arun Killu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300034) is a good snippet if you know what is going on, but nobody has explained what was the error on the original code. For people using `async` and `Promise` calls this is error is soo obvious but for people learning or without experience it's not so clear.

Here a simple explanation.

### The Bad code [image]

```js
var blob = items[i].getAsFile();

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
console.log(event.target.result)
}; // data url!
var source = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

Above code is trying to capture a binary string on `source` variable, however, [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) returns `undefined`. This is because the result will be available whenever the event `onload` will be triggered. As we can see, he was trying to `console.log` the `event.target.result` value, which is a wrong approach.

### The Good code [image]

Here is a step by step implementation:

```js
// 1. Create a FileReader instance
const reader = new FileReader()
// 2. Add a handler for the 'onload' event
reader.onload = (e) => {
    // 5. Get the result when the 'onload' event is triggered.
    const base64data = reader.result               
    console.log({base64data})
}
// 3. Add a handler for the 'onerror' event
reader.onerror = () => {                
    console.log('error')
}
// 4. Call 'readAsDataURL' method
reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob)
```

As you can see the last step is `5` and it is because it is an asynchronous call.

Here is a working example:

```js
const url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRuCp.png'

const fetchImage = async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors',})
  const blob = await response.blob()
  
  return blob
}

const loadImage = async () => {
  const imageBlob = await fetchImage(url)

  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = () => {
    const base64data = reader.result               
    console.log({base64data})
  }
  reader.onerror = () => {                
    console.log('error')
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob) 
}

loadImage()
```

#### Teo, what means asynchronous?

Well young Padawan, asynchronous means that we don't know when the result will be ready, it can be different in each system and depends on how heavy or complex is the process and also it can find some errors that will not produce any result at all.

So if a process is asynchronous is a good practice to encapsulate it using an `async` method and returning a `Promise` like this:

```js
const blobToBase64 = async blob => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = err => reject(err)
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  })
}
```

#### Ah okay Teo, but what is a Promise?

Good question my young fella. A `Promise` object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value. In other words, will tell us if the result is ready and will give us its value, otherwise will return an error.

Above code shows a function `blobToBase64` that will return a `Promise` This means that this function will return `reader.result` when it ready.

#### How can we integrate it into our code?

Super easy, just replace all the FileReader with the function `blobToBase64` defined above and call it like this `imageBase64 = await blobToBase64(imageBlob)`

Check this snippet:

```js
const url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRuCp.png'

const fetchImage = async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  })
  const blob = await response.blob()

  return blob
}

const blobToBase64 = async blob => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = err => reject(err)
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  })
}

const loadImage = async() => {
  const imageBlob = await fetchImage(url)
  const imageBase64 = await blobToBase64(imageBlob)
  
  console.log({imageBase64})
}

loadImage()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, usually you get `octet-stream` from `ajax` calls or `$http` service from angular. can you give an example of your code or share the image file you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026755/5372008 check this  answer I make about converting `svg` into a `png` format

Comment: Neither of your two examples appear to work, no image is displayed, and "imageBase64" is just "data:". I have tested in my environment as well with the same, if not worse, results. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6):

So the problem is that you want to upload a base 64 image and you have a blob url. Now the answer that will work on all html 5 browsers is:
Do:

```
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('myFileInputTag');
  var preview = document.getElementById('myImgTag');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
      preview.setAttribute('src', url);
  });
function Upload()
{
     // preview can be image object or image element
     var myCanvas = document.getElementById('MyCanvas');
     var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.drawImage(preview, 0,0);
     var base64Str = myCanvas.toDataURL();
     $.ajax({
         url: '/PathToServer',
         method: 'POST',
         data: {
             imageString: base64Str
         },
     success: function(data) { if(data && data.Success) {}},
     error: function(a,b,c){alert(c);}
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

async TypeScript variation:

```
async function blobToBase64Async(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onerror = (e) => reject(fileReader.error);
    fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
      const dataUrl = fileReader.result as string;
      // remove "data:mime/type;base64," prefix from data url
      const base64 = dataUrl.substring(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1);
      resolve(base64);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

Sample usage:

```
async function fetchToBase64Async(url: string, init?: RequestInit): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, init);
    if (!response.ok) {
      const responseText = await response.text();
      throw new Error("server status: " + response.status + "\n" + "server response:" + "\n" + responseText);
    }
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const base64 = await blobToBase64Async(blob);
    return base64;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("failed to fetch: " + url + "\n" + "caused by: " + e);
  }
}

async function demoUsage() {
  const base64 = await fetchToBase64Async("https://httpstat.us/200", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ...",
    }
  });
  console.log(base64);
}
```

Notes:

- I don't understand why some answers use the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/load_event) instead of the [`loadend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/loadend_event) event
- I don't understand why some answers call [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) before setting the event handler

Comment: You should use `load` instead of `loadend` because `loadend` fires in case of both success and error. That is, you have 2 error handlers, which is ambiguous (it's unclear who will handle the error first).

Answer (score 5):

you can fix problem by:

```
var canvas = $('#canvas'); 
var b64Text = canvas.toDataURL();
b64Text = b64Text.replace('data&colon;image/png;base64,','');
var base64Data = b64Text;
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use a simple wrapper around `FileReader` returning `Observable` (snippet is in `TypeScript`):

```
  function toBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return fromEvent(reader, 'load')
      .pipe(map(() => (reader.result as string).split(',')[1]));
  }
```

Usage:

```
toBase64(blob).subscribe(base64 => console.log(base64));
```

Answer (score 3):

Typescript version :

```
const blob2Base64 = (blob:Blob):Promise<string> => {
      return new Promise<string> ((resolve,reject)=> {
           const reader = new FileReader();
           reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
           reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result.toString());
           reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
       })
      }
```

usage:

```
blob2Base64(blob).then(res=>console.log(res))
```

Comment: The `onerror` callback argument is not an error. You should use `reader.onerror = () => reject(reader.error)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but

```
let encoded = btoa(await myblob.text());
```

... is all you need to do to encode a `Blob`'s data to base64. See [`Blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) and [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa).

Or if you want the whole thing as a promise:

```
let encode = myblob.text().then(btoa);
```

<sup>PS: To decode back to a Blob: `new Blob([atob(encoded)])`</sup>

Comment: May fail when the blob has special "chars": `DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Comment: @RoyShilkrot [Addressed in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem), with solutions (also mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa#unicode_strings) in `btoa` doc link in post).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something where I have access to base64 value to store into a list and for me adding event listener worked. You just need the FileReader which will read the image blob and return the base64 in the result.

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const supportedImages = []; // you can also refer to some global variable
    reader.addEventListener(
      'load',
      () => {
        // reader.result will have the required base64 image
        const base64data = reader.result;
        supportedImages.push(base64data); // this can be a reference to global variable and store the value into that global list so as to use it in the other part
      },
      false
    );
    // The readAsDataURL method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File.
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
 }
```

Final part is the readAsDataURL which is very important is being used to read the content of the specified Blob

Answer (score 0):

If your `"blob"` is an actual `Blob Object` and not a `blob url`, the conversion is pretty simple:

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
```

example of `Blob Object`:

```
console.log(blob)
```

output:

```
Blob {lastModified: 1658039931443, lastModifiedDate: Sun Jul 17 2022 08:38:51 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), name: '1.jpg', size: 35493, type: 'image/jpeg'}
    lastModified: 1658039931443
    lastModifiedDate: Sun Jul 17 2022 08:38:51 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
    name: "1.jpg"
    size: 35493
    type: "image/jpeg"
    [[Prototype]]: Blob
```

In my case, the `blob` was produced by `Compressorjs` (should you need image compression).

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can request the file as an array buffer then map it to base64

```js
this.http.get('./101.jpg', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).pipe(
    map(q => String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(q))),
    map(q => btoa(q)),
).subscribe(q => {
    console.log(q);
})
```