# nested post object with form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, postman

I have my Rails backend organized to receive a POST like this in a controller:

```
{
    "entry": {
        "title": {
        "media": {
              "description": "some text",
              "image": ...image here,
        }
    }
}
```

I can create the entry by POSTing a json like the above, with a base64 encoded image, but I would like to do this using formData instead (because the image might be large, or might even be a video...). I have tried this using Postman and I can create the entry with parameters as `entry[title]` etc, but how do I express the image attribute? Is it even possible? I tried `entry[media][image]`but that did not work (did not seemed right either...)

Is it possible to nest things like this when using formData?

Comment: I wasn't aware that formData can handle a larger image or video than doing it with the method you already have working. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I believe base64 encoding is making the media larger, which is what i want to avoid. I am not really sure if it is a good approach to send a mobile recorded video by base64 encoding it, is it?

Comment: how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931100/4887159

Comment: No you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Do something like this, depending on what is an array or not:

```
entry[0].title
entry[0].media.description
entry[0].media.image
```