# "Load" event on script with async and/or defer

Tags: javascript, html

When embedding scripts like:

```
<script src="..." async defer></script>
```

Is there a way to know when they're finished loading?

Usually when the `window.load` event is called, one would expect all scripts to be ready as well. But I don't know if that still holds when you load them with `async` or `defer`. I've read some docs online but couldn't find anything conclusive on this issue.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Answer:**
You could take advantage of the `onload` event attribute in order to perform some kind of **callback** once your script is loaded.

**Example:** 
In the example html script element below when the script (jquery library from google api) finishes loading asynchronously, an alert will pop up saying **'resource loaded'**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" async defer onload="alert('resource loaded');">
```

*Note: The src script will load very fast because it is hosted by google so the pop up will most likely appear as soon as the page/DOM has loaded.*

#### Edit: added important information originally from comment.

`window.onload` waits for **everything** to load before firing whereas `document.onload` fires when the Document Object Model (DOM) is ready.

So if you've got async scripts `document.onload` will execute first while `window.onload` will wait for those asynchronous scripts to finish loading.

To summarize:

- `window.onload` **will** take async scripts into account.
- `document.onload` **will not** take async scripts into account.

Comment: ok so the window.onload event doesnt take async scripts into account right?

Comment: window.onload waits for everything to load before firing whereas document.onload fires when the DOM is ready. So if you've got async scripts document.onload will execute first while window.onload will wait. So window.onload will take asyncscripts into account

Comment: Can you please share a document or blog where it can be followed further?

Answer (score 4):

Emphasis mine:

> Is there a way to know when **they**'re finished loading?
>
> Usually when the window.load event is called, one would expect all scripts to be ready as well. But **I don't know if that still holds when you load them with async or defer**. I've read some docs online but couldn't find anything conclusive on this issue.

Addressing the points in bold (for specific single scripts you can use their onload events), the TL;DR is:

- The `document.DOMContentLoaded` event will happen after *all normal and deferred scripts* load and execute, but doesn't care about async scripts.
- The `window.load` event will happen after *all normal, async, and deferred scripts* load and execute.
- Note: A script that has both async *and* deferred set will act as deferred on legacy browsers that don't support async, and will act as async otherwise. So the safe bet is to think of them as async.

---

The HTML specification does say this, albeit indirectly. The spec [defines three distinct script collections](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#set-of-scripts-that-will-execute-as-soon-as-possible) that every document has (I'm naming them *S1*, *S2*, and *S3*):

> Each Document has a **set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible**, which is a set of script elements, initially empty. [S1]
>
> Each Document has a **list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible**, which is a list of script elements, initially empty. [S2]
>
> Each Document has a **list of scripts that will execute when the document has finished parsing**, which is a list of script elements, initially empty. [S3]

Just above that, in the [section about preparing script elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#prepare-the-script-element), it details how scripts are distributed to those collections. Generally speaking, during load:

- These are placed in S1 (see step 31.2.2):

  - All async external (scripts with a `src`) scripts.
  - All async module (depends on `type` attribute) scripts.
- These are placed in S2 (*defer* is irrelevant for these) (see step 31.3.2):

  - Non-async, injected (e.g. by the browser) external scripts.
  - Non-async, injected module scripts.
- These are placed in S3 (see step 31.4):

  - Deferred, non-async, non-injected external scripts.
  - All non-async, non-injected module scripts (*defer* is irrelevant for these).
- These are executed synchronously and aren't placed in any of the collections:

  - Non-deferred, non-async, non-injected external scripts (see step 31.5).
  - All inline (without a `src`) scripts (neither *async* nor *defer* apply to these) (see step 32).

In simplified terms:

- S1 contains all the async external/module scripts.
- S2 contains all the non-async injected external/module scripts.
- S3 contains all the deferred external/module scripts.
- Inline scripts and vanilla external scripts are executed as they're loaded and parsed (as part of the parsing operation).

The HTML spec then goes on to define [what happens after parsing is complete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end), where the relevant parts are, *in order*:

- Change document's ready state to "interactive"; fires *document.readystatechange* (see step 3)
- Execute all scripts in S3 (deferred non-async non-injected) (see step 5)
- Queued (will happen >= now): Fire a *DOMContentLoaded* event on *document* (see step 6.2)
- Wait until all scripts in S1 (async) and S2 (non-async injected) have been executed (see step 7)
- Wait until any other load-blocking operations have been completed (see step 8)
- Queued:

  - Change document's ready state to "complete"; fires *document.readystatechange* (see step 9.1)
  - Fire a *load* event on *window* (see step 9.5)
  - Fire a *pageshow* event on *window* (see step 9.11)
  - If the document is in some container (e.g. an iframe), fire a *load* event on the container (see link in step 9.12)

In simplified terms, the events that depend on script executions are:

- *document.DOMContentLoaded* happens after all the deferred scripts are executed.
- *document.readystatechange* ("complete") and *window.load* happen after *all* scripts are executed.
- *window.pageshow* also happens after all scripts are executed, although it happens at other times later, too.
- If there's a container like an iframe or something, its *load* event happens after all scripts are executed as well.

Btw, as for scripts with both *async* and *defer* set, [the part describing these attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer) says:

> The defer attribute may be specified even if the async attribute is specified, to cause legacy web browsers that only support defer (and not async) to fall back to the defer behavior instead of the blocking behavior that is the default.

For "modern" browsers, I assume the behavior when both are specified is to just adhere to the logic above, i.e. those scripts end up in S1 and *defer* is essentially ignored.

So uh... yup.