# When does onload fire for async script?

Tags: javascript, html

The following snippet is taken from [an example in Google API doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gapi-callback). The intriguing part of this snippet is that `onload` event handler in the two `<script async>` in `<head>` are defined later in the `<body>`. Does the `onload` event in the async script only  fire after the `<body>` are parsed? Does any spec provide such guarantee? Or this code is only correct under the implied assumption that these two particular scripts in `<head>` takes a long time to fetch and execute?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoad()"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisInit()"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    function gapiLoad() {
       // do something 
    }

    function gisInit() {
       // do something 
    }

    // there are other stuffs...

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: these two : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193553/load-event-on-script-with-async-and-or-defer   &   https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onload EventHandler Supports these HTML tags: `<body>, <frame> (deprecated), <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>, <track>, <svg>, <use>, <foreignObject>, <image>, <object>, <embed`. (Merci to @Kaiido for completing this list.)

If you want to be sure that your JS only runs when the DOM is loaded, you can load a handler function from the body tag.

**Note** You need to know when using onload with async that when scripts are loaded asynchronously, they delay the onload event. Often, asynchronously loaded scripts load other scripts.

```js
function start() {
  gapiLoad();
  gisInit();
}

function gapiLoad() {
  console.log(1)
  // do something 
}

function gisInit() {
  console.log(2)
  // do something 
}
    
    // there are other stuffs...
```

```html
<head>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" ></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
</head>

<body onload="start()">
```

Comment: `<frame>` is deprecated, `onload` also fires on `<track>`, `<svg>`, `<use>`, `<foreignObject>`, `<image>`, `<object>`, `<embed>` and probabbly others I forget right now. But that's not the point of the question anyway.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the hint. I will updated my answer on this point.

Answer (score 3):

No `async` doesn't ensure the script will be executed after the document has been parsed. It will load the script in parallel and execute it **as soon as possible**, so if the fetching of the script finishes before the parser reaches the `<script>` where your callbacks are being defined, that would be a problem indeed:

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoad()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisInit()"></script>
<!-- This one is blocking for at least 3s -->
<script src="https://deelay.me/3000/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function gapiLoad() {
   console.log("loaded");
}
function gisInit() {
   console.log("init");
}
</script>
```

`defer` does that, but if both `defer` and `async` are set, `async`'s behavior wins, so we have to ensure only `defer` is set.

```html
<script defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoad()"></script>
<script defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisInit()"></script>
<!-- this one is blocking for at least 3s -->
<script src="https://deelay.me/3000/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function gapiLoad() {
   console.log("loaded");
}
function gisInit() {
   console.log("init");
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Kalido What you are think about to attach the onload event to the body tag?

Comment: They may not need to wait for all image resources to load.

Comment: @kaiido when you say "they don't risk facing this problem", do you mean the onload handler are only called after the body is parsed?  Also, according to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615101/what-does-async-defer-do-when-used-together?noredirect=1&lq=1), when both `async` and `defer` are used,  `async` take precedence in modern browser, so `defer` has no effect here.

Comment: @sgu Dang! you're completely right, the defer is simply ignored, I always get this wrong because I don't understand why the heck they made it work like that. This will bite me someday... As for the attribute, no I mean that the HTML parser will attach the handler even before it set the src (or right after), so the parallel fetching will always end after the handler has been attached.

Comment: @Kaiido But the fact that "parallel fetching will always end after the handler has been attached" doesn't guarantee the correctness. The key question is whether the function `gapiLoad` is defined when the  `<script>` 's `onload` handler is called.  Note that the function `gapiLoad` is defined in the `<body>` while the script src is fetched in `<head>`. In other words, is it possible for the browser to fire the `onload` event of the async script and call the `gapiLoad` before it finishes parsing `<body>`.

Comment: @sgu Once again you're right... I don't know what I have with this question ;-) So indeed if the script is executed before the parser reached the callbacks definitions this will fail.