# Converting MediaRecorder audio to base64

Tags: javascript, html, audio, base64, blob

I am using the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record audio on my page.

I need to convert this audio to base64.

Have a look at [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/).

Each time new data is available, it pushes that data to an array, like this:

```
function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}
```

Then, it combines all that data like this:

```
var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
```

So how would I convert this `superBuffer` to base64?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using FileReader Object.

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(superBuffer); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
   base64 = reader.result;
   base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
   console.log(base64 );
}
```

Answer referred from [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64).

Read more about [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for better understanding.

Comment: This answer is incredibly useful specially if you are trying to use Node's FS api to write the base64 encoded blobs into a file. Not doing the `.split(',')[1]` part causes corrupt webm files to be generated.