# blob to base64 converstion javascript

Tags: javascript, html, base64, blob

I am trying to parse blob object into base64 string in javascript. Please help. my code is

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
    // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
    var buffer = reader.result;
    var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var binary = String.fromCharCode.apply(window, view);
    var base64 = btoa(binary);
    cb(base64);
    console.log(base64);
}); 

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data.blob);
```

Comment: So what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)

Answer (score 6):

You may try this-

```
var blob = //your blob data;

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64data = reader.result;                
    console.log(base64data);
    return;
}
```

Refer- [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)