# How to pass a blob created in javascript to JSF bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

My client side code deals with canvas drawing, and i generate a blob zip file of the shapes using javascript. 
I want to use the zip at the server side. However, I am not able to find any solution.

I have tried using remote command, but using that i can only pass string parameters to the JSF bean. 
I tried hacking the primefaces fileUpload plugin somehow so that I could pass my blob to the backing bean, but that also didn't work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass blob from JavaScript to JSF bean by encoding blob to some string representation, for example, to **Base64** and passing it to Primefaces  `p:remoteCommand`, sending it to managed bean and finally decoding it there back to byte array.

Procedure would be following:

1. Convert blob to Base64

   ```
    function prepareAndSendBlobToManagedBean(){
               //zipped file as blob
               var blob=...;
               ///convert blob to Base64 string
               var blobBase64String=convertToBase64(blob);
               sendBlobBase64([{name : 'blobBase64Name', value : blobBase64String}]);
           }
   ```

(for converting from blob to base64 reffer to this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64))

2. Add p:remoteCommand to your page

   ```
   <p:remoteCommand name="sendBlobBase64" 
                    actionListener="#{yourBean.onBlobBase64Sent}" process="@this"/>
   ```
3. In managed bean named *yourBean* you can catch it with

   ```
   public void onBlobBase64Sent() {
      String blobBase64 = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("blobBase64Name");
      byte[]blob=java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(blobBase64);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to do using base64. But I am now running into problems(je when the blob is large(java heap space). Is there a mechanism, where I could use byte stream, instead of String from RequestParameterMap

Comment: @AshishMathew, I suppose that, in that case, you will need to implement some kind of 'chunk-by-chunk' file upload procedure. I suggest that you create another question about that or search SO for ideas.