# How to send blob appended in formData to php

Tags: javascript, php

**Issue** : While uploading large image files i recognized that while uploading on my `AWS server` having `1gb memory` uses it's full capacity, it goes upto `932 mb` usage which causes crash to the process. I was saving that image in the form of DataURI and then I read somewhere that saving it in the form of `blob` can solve my problem. So i want to append that blob to formData and send to server and this is the reason i come up with this question. However if any else suggestion regarding the same problem to save image more efficient way when memory is concerned, will be appreciated.

**Motive**

I want to send an image to the server side as in the form of a `blob`.

**What I have done**

I am currently having a `dataURI` which I have converted into a `blob`. Further, i append that blob to `formData` and try to send it to server side/php using ajax.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function convertURIToImageData(dataURI) {
// convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  var byteString;
  if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  else
    byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

// separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

// write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
 }
//
const dataURIconverter = () =>{
  let img;
  var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // cross domain
  // create an empty canvas element
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  image.onload = function () {
    //Set canvas size is same as the picture
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    // draw image into canvas element
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    // get canvas contents as a data URL (returns png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    // console.log(dataURL)
    let blob = convertURIToImageData(dataURL)
    console.log(blob)
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('blobImage',blob)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: formData,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
  }
    image.src = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg"
 }

 dataURIconverter()
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  var_dump($_POST['blobImage'])
  var_dump($_POST);
        //var_dump($_FILES['image']);

  //$name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 //echo $name;
 //echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 //$status = move_uploaded_file($name, $_FILES['image']['name']);

//echo 'successfully stored at '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
```

**Error**

I am receiving null as in console and i also checked the headers where i see `formData` with the name 
[image]

As you can see, `$_POST` showing the blob but `$_POST['blobImage']` is showing null.

**Solution I require**:

i am not that quick to `php` so i am not sure if i am sending the `blob` in the right way or receiving it.

I have provided my all possible efforts i have taken to achieve my motive.

Thanks to the community for help.

Comment: I always recommend base64 data when it comes to images via ajax. So maybe convert your blob into base64 string before sending via ajax. How to? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/1887622

Comment: * I read here on stack that saving it in the form of `blob` can be efficient* Could you please provide a link to this advice?

Comment: If i could bookmarked that, i was searching regarding the crash issue, increased all possible limits in ini file. Than i reached to conversion to blob for such problem. It seems i am wrong with the approach. If you help me out with the advise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following three properties on your jQuery Ajax call , they are required for blobs :

```
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

Then do not use **formData** in the data property of your Ajax Call , you simply need to add your created blob. 
Also add a small rendering callback (apart from the console.log you already use) to print the Image. Your AJAX call gets like this :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: blob,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        document.write("<img src='"+data+"'></img>");
    })
```

Change your PHP code to the following :

```
<?php
  $res = file_get_contents("php://input");
  echo "data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($res);
?>
```

As far as the "**php://input**" use is concerned. It returns all the raw data that come after the headers of your request and it does not care what type they are which is pretty handy in most cases. Whereas **$_POST** will only wrap the data that have been passed with the following Content-Types :

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

If you really want to use **FormData** then you can change the request to the following :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check.php',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

And you should also change your PHP file to get the **$_FILE**. Sending data this way , the **Content-Type** of the Request will be "multipart/form-data" which will have blobs , images and generally files on the **$_FILES** and the rest on the **$_POST** so the "**php://input**" will not be helpful.

```
<?php
  var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Also keep in mind that when uploading blobs this way , they will get a random name , if you are not going to be generating filenames on the Server-Side (which you probably should in most cases) and want a specific name designated by the uploader , then you can pass it along with the FormData like :

```
formData.append('blobImage',blob, "MyBloBName");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, however i want to send formdata as i have multiple images to send. i want to send a formData , Is it not possible to send appended blob ?

Comment: i just updated my question where i mentioned the reason behind my question

Comment: Why not spawn multiple requests to the server that are a lot more controllable , easier to fail-safe and track than creating a big request with a lot of blobs? You are also mentioning memory issues , the largest the request the more memory it will consume , cause the Server needs to allocate memory for all the blobs on the request. You are better of going with multiple single requests in my opinion.

Comment: I have included your request to use the FormData in my Answer.

Comment: After struggling, so much thank you for the answer. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `contentType: false` in your jQuery Ajax call , you can still use the same code with  `formData` and then access the file on the server through `$_FILES['blobImage']`

Comment: it returns an array of 5 elements, where blob as an string showing: 
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "blob"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error"]=>
  int(1)
  ["size"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: Do you have enough upload_max_filesize in your php.ini? See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: yeah, its set to max. I have done all the concerned issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $_REQUEST, and therefore $_GET and $_POST objects have a limitation to the number of characters available to them.

```
post_max_size
```

in PHP.ini controls the maximum size of post.

Browsers and their implementations of $_GET control the limit of a $_GET request. As it appears in their URL bar. For example IE9's limit is 2000 characters so if your blob ends up as anything more than 2000 characters in the $_GET Request. The general consensus is that $_GET requests should be much less than 255 bytes. And if you approach this limit be careful because older browsers and protocols are completely unprepared for this.