# HTML5 File API - Save blob to file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery, which I think should pass a sliced file to PHP:

```
var blob = f.slice(start, stop);

var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append('fileUpload', blob, f.name);

$.ajax({
     url: 'save.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function(msg){
          alert("Success: " + msg);
     },
     error: function(bla, msg){
          alert("Fail: " + msg);
     }
});
```

However, I'm not sure what the PHP should look like to save the blob to a file.

The intention is for the browser to slice the file and then save the output.

Answer (score 0):

Receive it as a file at your server

```
<?php
  //var_dump($_FILES) // check if you received it or not
  $blob = $_FILES('fileUpload');
  file_put_contents('/path/to/new/file_name', $blob);

?>
```

You might want to save the file to a tmp location first, then do some checks on it before you move it to a final location (with PHPs rename() function).

Btw: why not just save the BLOB to DB? That is a legitimate way of handling files these days, that's what the BLOB MySQL data type is for after all.

I already asked this and it worked, have a look: [send formData appended with blob to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210228/how-to-send-blob-appended-in-formdata-to-php)

Answer (score -2):

Due to `contentType: false` the data is available in `$_FILES` rather than `$_POST`. One way to do it, is like so:

```
<?php

    move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], 
        $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']
    ); 

?>
```