# Fetch image from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**Q1)** In my reactjs application, I am trying to fetch an API from my backend Nodejs server. The API responds with an image file on request.

I can access and see image file on http://192.168.22.124:3000/source/592018124023PM-pexels-photo.jpg

But in my reactjs client side I get this error on console log.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

**Reactjs:**

```
let fetchURL = 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/source/';
  let image = name.map((picName) => {
    return picName
  })

  fetch(fetchURL + image)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(images => console.log(fetchURL + images));
```

**Nodejs:**

```
app.get('/source/:fileid', (req, res) => {
const { fileid } = req.params;
res.sendFile(__dirname + /data/ + fileid); 
});
```

**Is there any better way to do than what I am doing above?**

**Q2)** Also, how can I assign a value to an empty variable (which lives outside the fetch function)
jpg = fetchURL + images;
So I can access it somewhere.

Comment: The image is not in JSON format. Did you mean to use `.blob()` or something rather than `.json()`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch "Checking that the fetch was successful" section

Comment: You can't use `response.json()` to fetch an image cause it's not a json content.

Comment: @CertainPerformance
Using blob I get this on console log: 
http://192.168.22.124:3000/source/[object Blob]

Comment: Did you read the section in the link I posted?

Comment: you should encode the image in base64 in order to use it in json.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have read it and now I am getting some random strings:  blob:http://localhost:3001/5970bae1-06a7-4882-a42e-63bb01a13f5f

Comment: For what it is worth, if the response body of an API endpoint has a variety of content types, it would be more appropriate to check `Content-Type` in the response header to determine whether to invoke `response.json()` or `response.blob()`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The response from the server is an image file, not JSON formatted text.
You'll want to read the response content as a Blob ("binary large object"), with [Response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob).

In this function we fetch a blob:

```
async function fetchBlob(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    // Here is the significant part 
    // reading the stream as a blob instead of json
    return response.blob();
}
```

Then, you can create an object URL and assign the source of an image to this generated URL in your React application:

```
const [imageSourceUrl, setImageSourceUrl] = useState("");

const downloadImageAndSetSource = async (imageUrl) => {
    const image = await fetchBlob(imageUrl);
    setImageSourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(image));
}
```

Comment: I get this on console log: 192.168.22.124:3000/source/[object Blob]

Comment: Yes, because `images` is indeed a Blob now. Basically a file. You can then use `var url = URL.createObjectURL(images)` to create a URL for that image.

Comment: Now I get this: 
  
blob:http://localhost:3001/613348fe-52e4-4baa-8e76-e48332494e19
Am I still missing something?

Comment: How can I access the image file url now? 
When I click on localhost:3001/613348fe-52e4-4baa-8e76-e48332494e19  I get redirected to my sign up page.

Comment: You can't omit the `blob:` at the beginning of the URL. What do you want to do with the image? If you simply want to show it on the page, then why not just use a `<img>` tag?

Comment: I am trying to save the blob in a variable outside the fetch which is not working and shows undefined. I am passing that variable to another component where it returns image like this <img src={`${jpg}`} />

Comment: Why not just pass the `fetchUrl + image` immediately to that component? Why do you need to fetch the image data at all? How do you see that the variable is `undefined` outside of the function? Using `console.log`?

Comment: Yes, console log.
Assigning value to a variable that lives outside the fetch is undefined

Comment: Could be that the `console.log` prints the variable before it is assigned inside the `fetch(...).then(...)`

Comment: this worked for me! thanks a lot, any tips on how i could cache that image? could i save it to local storage as a blob?

Comment: You can save the blob as a Base64 encoded string in local storage. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64

Answer (score 11):

Equivalent to solution by @maxpaj, but using async and await.

```
async function load_pic() {
    
        const url = '<REPLACE-WITH-URL>'
    
        const options = {
            method: "GET"
        }
    
        let response = await fetch(url, options)
    
        if (response.status === 200) {
            
            const imageBlob = await response.blob()
            const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
    
            const image = document.createElement('img')
            image.src = imageObjectURL
    
            const container = document.getElementById("your-container")
            container.append(image)
        }
        else {
            console.log("HTTP-Error: " + response.status)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is 4 years old and I think in 2022 there are many ways to solve this. This is ES6 version using async calls.

First, I don't know if you are trying to download the image or insert the image into a `img` tag. So I will assume we want to download the image.

The process is simple: a) [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the image as a `blob`; b) convert blob to `Base64` using [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL); and c) trigger the download using a ghost `a` tag.

```js
const $btn = document.getElementById('downloadImage')
const url = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tksproduction/bmtimages/pY3BnhPQYpTxasKfx.jpeg'

const fetchImage = async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const blob = await response.blob()
  
  return blob
}

const downloadImage = async url => {
  const imageBlob = await fetchImage(url)
  const imageBase64 = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob)

  console.log({imageBase64})
  
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.setProperty('display', 'none')
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
  a.href = imageBase64
  a.click()
  a.remove()
}

$btn.onclick = event => downloadImage(url)
```

```html
<button id="downloadImage">Download Image</button>
```

### Note:

StackOverflow uses a sandboxed `iframe`'s so we cannot test the download here, but you can use my [codepen](https://codepen.io/teocci/pen/zYjJyrb)

Comment: what if i want to show image in <img> tag ?

Comment: just load the `imageBase64` on a `img` or `canvas` tag.