# google chrome doesnt show photos on my websites

Tags: html, google-chrome, security

I want to show some images from another websites in my website. This is the code:

```
<img src="https://www.alaedin.travel/Files/Original/Hotels/mashhad/aban/Alaedin-Travel-Agency-Mashhad-Aban-Hotel-Facade-1.jpg">
```

Images arent shown in Chrome. But I can see them in FireFox.
whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with chrome being stuck in redirection as you can see in the logs:
[image: chrome network log]
I am not sure why is that behavior. I suggest that you store these pictures in a static folder as a temporary solution if you can, or try using fetch requests while enabling CORS.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please help me with fetch requests while enabling CORS? I dont know any thing about it. I'm using an API and then I store all the data in my DB. The image address is read from my DB.

Comment: @Hajar Enabling CORS is simple but tricky, and I also think both websites needs to have it enabled in order to have sharing enabled. You can read more about CORS in this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Enabling CORS fairly similar throughout back-end technologies, so just search how you could enable CORS using your backend technologies. As for fetching images, try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248329/fetch-image-from-api).