# How to load an image from url using Gtk3 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, networking, gtk3

How to go about loading an image from the internet using Gtk3 with javascript?

I tried using

```
var image = new Image();
image.src(url);
```

But this gives an error ->
JS ERROR: ReferenceError: Image is not defined

Any helps?

Thanks.

//Update
Since their was not enough information available above, I`ll post it down here ->

```
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

let app = new Gtk.Application({ application_id: 'org.gtk.ExampleApp' });


app.connect("activate", ()=>{

let win = new Gtk.Window({application : app});
let img = new Gtk.Image();

let url = 'https://spotlightreport.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/AC-DC-SHOT-IN-THE-DARK-PACK-SHOT-1920x1920.jpg';

let input_stream = Gio.MemoryInputStream.new_from_data(url, null);
let pixbuf = Gdk.GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_stream(input_stream);

img.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);    

win.connect('destroy', ()=>{win.close();});
win.set_default_size(450,250);
win.show_all();
});
app.run([]);
```

I actually want to load the image from url directly i.e. without downloading it. And i came across a post to fetch data using javascript functions but it didn`t work. How do i fetch the image and show it?
I actually tried to do this -> [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248329/fetch-image-from-api)

Comment: Maybe `image.src = url` ?

Comment: Well it says that Image() is not defined, so changing `image.src(url)` to  `image.src = url` does`nt change anything.

Comment: If you type `var image = new Image()` in a javascript console, you will see that it works. If it doesn't work in your project the problem must be somewhere else. You'll have to post a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little code to go on here, but I can imagine several reasons why it doesn't work:

- you didn't import the Gtk module

```js
imports.gi.versions.Gtk = "3.0";
const { Gtk } = imports.gi;
```

- you should add the namespace when referencing the class

```js
const image = new Gtk.Image()  // Not `new Image()`
```

- `src()` is not a method that exists in `Gtk.Image` nor does it mention that anywhere. You can find the JS documentation of Gtk.Image at https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gtk30-image/ . As you'll see there, there is no method to load a Gtk.Image from a random URL (unless it happens to be a file). So you'll first have to download the contents of the URL, make a Gdk.Pixbuf out of it, and then use that for your Gtk.Image

In any case: I think it's best for you to first follow the [GTK3 in GJS guide](https://gjs.guide/guides/gtk/3/) (there's also [a section on using Gtk.Image](https://gjs.guide/guides/gtk/3/09-images.html#gtk-image)) and start from some smaller examples. Once you learn the basics and start feeling comfortable with GJS, you can then proceed to start implementing custom stuff.

Comment: I updated the question maybe it`s clear now.