# How to open a picture from an api call in js?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am making a js POST api call to a server. It responds back with a .jpg image.
Here is my code:

```
 function arCall(url = '', data = {}) {
  var ARCSRFToken;
  fetch('/session/token')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    ARCSRFToken = text
  })
  .then(() => {
  //console.log(ARCSRFToken)
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/html, */*',
      'X-CSRF-Token': `${ARCSRFToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
})
}

arCall('<The URL>', { id: 100 });
```

For the `console.log(data)` line, I get a response `[img name].jpg`. But, the image itself doesn't display on the page.

I looked at this question [Fetch image from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248329/fetch-image-from-api) and altered my code based on it but that still did not seem to do the trick. Now, all I get is a URL and when I open it, it says page not found.

```
 function arCall(url = '', data = {}) {
  var ARCSRFToken;
  fetch('/session/token')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    ARCSRFToken = text
  })
  .then(() => {
  //console.log(ARCSRFToken)
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/html, */*',
      'X-CSRF-Token': `${ARCSRFToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.blob();
  })
  .then(imageBlob => {
    const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob)
    console.log(imageObjectURL)
  })
})
}

arCall('<The URL>', { id: 100 });
```

The only thing I want to do is display the .jpg picture on the page.

Comment: where do you want to show it? do you want to show it on the ```DOM```?

Comment: Yeah, I want to show the image in the `DOM`

Comment: Please add your frontend code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either create an image element or find one in your dom.

Create an image element:

```js
const imgUrl = "http://..."
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = imgUrl;
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);
```

Or find one on in your DOM:

```js
const imgUrl = "http://..."
const imgInDom = document.findElementById("someId")
imgInDom.src = imgUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get a response [img name].jpg

So you get a piece of **text** which gives you the file name of the image. This is the *file name* of an image and not an actual image.

> I looked at this question Fetch image from API

Stop. You have the *file name* of an image and not an actual image. That question is all about when you have a URL to the actual image.

> But, the image itself doesn't display on the page.

You are passing a string with the file name to `console.log`.

There's no reason why that should cause the image to display on the page.

If you want to display an image on the page then you need to [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) an [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), then [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) it's `src` attribute to be a URL that points to *the image* (maybe you can work out what that is based on the filename in the string, if not you need to make improvements to the API) and then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the image element to somewhere inside the document.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it easily in this way.

```js
<body>
    <img id="imgTag" src="" alt="">
</body>
<script>
    const imgTag = document.getElementById("imgTag")
    imgTag.setAttribute("src" , 'https://picsum.photos/200/300')
</script>
```

You can use `setAttribute` method to set `src` attribute on your `img` tag.