# Google Picker API to read the content of the file

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to consume Google Picker API from SAP UI5 application. 
I need to read the file content as BLOB and convert to Base64 string. 
I have reached till getting the URL for the file from the response of Google Picker API. However, further to read the BLOB which I can then use to convert it to Base64 string, I need directions. Kindly advise.

[Google Picker API documentation referred](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

The below code helps in getting the metadata of the file:

```js
function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        }
        var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
      }
```

This helps in obtaining metadata. However I need to read the content of the file. Either as BLOB content or Base64 string.

Samad.

Comment: Hi, you can look at link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64. also, can you provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Jasbir I need to get the content of the selected file in Binary format. I need to later convert the content into a Base64 string to be used for another API input.

Comment: So which sapui5 control you using to upload files? I can help you with getting content. Another thing if you are not using any up[laod control, are you trying to read content via odata read call?

Comment: Hi @jasbir : Currently I have used files.get and simulated in POSTMAN to check if its working. I think this should be ok, will try out in the system and if there are any hiccups, I will get back. Thanks for supporting me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Google Drive file is being picked, you could use the Google Drive REST API. Specifically, you could use [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to download a file, and then process it further. If it is a Google Doc, you would use [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to convert it first.

Also see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rikusv. From data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0], am able to get the metadata of the document, however I need to get the content as binary data. With files.get, will I be able to get the content as BLOB.

Comment: Yes, using `alt=media`. See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: Thanks @rikusv. I would like to know if there is any pricing for Google Picker API or the other Files related methods as I couldn't see information under https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/.

Comment: As far as I know it is free.