# Angular 2 Typescript retrieving jpeg image from file system conversion issue

Tags: angular, image, base64, blob, httpclient

Because of the way I'm normally getting image data normally from an HTTP response supplying image data from the database, it is a base64 encoded value of the image.  If it isn't present, I am trying to substitute a default image.

An example of the html to display the image is like:

```
        <img [src]="'data:'+sample.mimetype+';base64,'+sample.value"
                alt="" width="75%"  />
```

The call I'm currently making to retrieve the image returns a blob.  (note I'm currently looking at the entire response only to help try to figure out what I am getting).  If the answer is using a different type of image response, I'm all ears. Here is the current call to retrieve the image from the file system.

```
    return this.httpClient
        .get<any>('./assets/images/face-not-avail.jpg', {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' })
        .map(response =>{
            console.log('face response ' + response);
            return response.body;
        })
        .catch(this.errorHelperService.handleError);
```

Here is the contents of the image response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC3V4.jpg)

But I am having trouble figuring out how to turn that blob into the type of base64 encoded value attrubute that I normally am dealing with.  I won't list everything I have tried...  But I can't seem to get access to the blob data.  The blob type is image/jpeg as expected.

I've been looking around, but nothing seems to fit.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why convert it to base64? Why not just set the `src` to that url?

Comment: The closest I seem to have gotten is using a FileReader, readAsText and onload using reader.result.  But the image is not displaying.  Thinking maybe it wasn't base64 encoded, I tried to btoa the result.  But that caused an error.

Comment: I would rather leave the page definition alone and just supply a new value.  Normally I don't have an image source, just contents.

Comment: What error did it cause?

Comment: GET unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,%EF%BF%BD%EF*** more data ***D%08 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: I have also tried to btoa and or atob the results for kicks just to see, and both get the error:    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: The image data I normally get from the server starts like "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBA"

Comment: The image data in the reader.result looks starts like "����JFIFxx��:ExifMM*QQQ��C"

Comment: The first error you got about the URL is because the URL needs sanitising. Was this code working previously? For the second error, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64