# How to convert image into base64?

Tags: javascript, base64url

I have seen many tutorials about converting image to base64. The work I did is based on that. I have created a function inside which this conversion will take place. ButI need to pass image like below function and get console.log like below.

I am not sure how to do it?

```
  getPDF() {
    let image = "assets/icon/logo.png";
    let imageData = this.getBase64Image(image);
    console.log("imageData", imageData);
  }

  getBase64Image(img) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", img, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      console.log(this.response);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        var res = event.target["result"];
      }
      var file = this.response;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/11168593)

Comment: Take a look at this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img

Comment: @jro I went through it But I want to console at first function

Comment: var reader = new FileReader(); var file = this.response; reader.readAsDataURL(file);reader.onload = function (event) {
        var res =reader.result; console.log(res);
      }

Answer (score 1):

To receive the base64 value in the `getPDF` function you can use promises.

```
getPDF() {
    let image = "assets/icon/logo.png";
    this.getBase64Image(image).then(imageData => {
       console.log("imageData", imageData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}

getBase64Image(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", img, true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
          console.log(this.response);
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (event) {
            resolve(event.target["result"]);
          }
          reader.onerror = function(e) {
             reject(e);
          };
          var file = this.response;
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
        xhr.send();
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @abadalyan, return a Promise from your `getBase64Image`.

Also do not forget to check the status of the response with `readyState` and `status` and handle any errors using `XMLHttpRequest.onerror` and `XMLHttpRequest.ontimeout` using the `reject` callback of the Promise.

You also have to check the `FileReader` errors with `FileReader.onerror` and `FileReader.onabort`, or you could use the `FileReader.loadend` callback instead of `FileReader.load` to make sure the promise always resolves even when you get a read error.

Here is an example with error handling:

```js
function getBase64Image(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        reader.onerror = e => reject(new Error('Reading error.', e));
        reader.onabort = e => reject(new Error('Reading abort.', e));
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      } else {
        reject(request.statusText);
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = e => reject(new Error('Network error.', e));
    xhr.ontimeout = e => reject(new Error('Timeout error.', e));
    xhr.send();
  });
}

getBase64Image('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://loremflickr.com/100/100').then(image => {
  console.log(image);
  document.querySelector('#img1').src = image;
}).catch(e => console.error(e.message || e));
  
getBase64Image('wrong-url').then(image => {
  console.log(image);
  document.querySelector('#img2').src = image;
}).catch(e => console.error(e.message || e));
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="" alt="No image yet">
<img id="img2" src="" alt="No image yet">
```