# Capacitor download and open file from api

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working on an Angular Ionic 7 App with capacitor 5. At one page of my app is a list of different files (pdf, txt,csv). The user can select a file and it should download to the device.
I tryed to create a Object Url and open it with window.open(fileURL), but nothing happens, also no error.
I tryed the library @capacitor/filesystem with downloadFile() Api. The result contins a blob but I'm not able to store it on the device. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
 Filesystem.downloadFile({ path: Directory.Data, url: url, directory: Directory.Data }).then((res) => {
    console.log('download finished');
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a PDF File from Blob with Ionic FileOpener and Capacitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071567/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-from-blob-with-ionic-fileopener-and-capacitor)

Comment: No, it is using fileOpener, which is not working for android 11 or later https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: Yeh.. But there is a Library for that now. But I'll post you some Guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Raphaël Balet's Answer I played around and found a shorter solution. For the downloadFile() api use at least the file name to store the file inside the directory. As url i use an api path.

```
 // download the file to file system or open it in browser
  selectFile() {
    const url = this.createFileUrl('api/issues/attachement/' + this.messageId + '/' + this.attachment.id);
  
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      Filesystem.downloadFile({
        path: this.attachment.attachmentName,
        url: url,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
      }).then((res: DownloadFileResult) => {
        this._openFileWithType(res.path, this.attachment.attachmentType);
      });
    } else {
      Browser.open({ url: url });
    }
  }

  //  Open the file
  private async _openFileWithType(filePath: string, fileType: string) {
    const fileOpenerOptions: FileOpenerOptions = {
      filePath: filePath,
      contentType: fileType,
    };

    await FileOpener.open(fileOpenerOptions)
      .then(() => {
        // 'File is opened'
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

We'll be using the [FileOpener library](https://github.com/capacitor-community/file-opener) from the capacitor community. together with the [write_blob library](https://github.com/diachedelic/capacitor-blob-writer#readme) which isn't obligated, but is faster and more reliable.

### How to

1. Download the libraries

```
npm install @capacitor-community/file-opener
npm install capacitor-blob-writer
npx cap sync
```

```js
// Not required step, just cleaner ;)
export interface CustomFile {
  title: string, 
  url: string, 
  path: string, 
  mineType: string 
}
```

```js
// 2. Import it into your file (I'm using a services)
import { FileOpener, FileOpenerOptions } from '@capacitor-community/file-opener'
import write_blob from 'capacitor-blob-writer'
import { Directory, Filesystem } from '@capacitor/filesystem'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OpenLinkService {
  progress = 0 // If you wish to show a loader :)
  downloadingUrls = [] // Avoid downloading multiple time the same asset

  constructor() {}

// 3. We'll be preparing & downloading the file
  private async _downloadAndOpenFiles(file: CustomFile) {
   if(this.downloadingUrls.includes(file.url)) return
   this.downloadingUrls.push(file.url)

    this._httpClient
      .get(url, {
        responseType: 'blob',
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: async (event) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
            this.progress = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total)
          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            this.progress = 100

            const filePath = await this._getFilePath(file.title, event.body)

            await this._openFileWithType(filePath, file.mineType)
            this.progres = 100
            this.downloadingUrls = this.downloadingUrls.filter((dUrl) => dUrl !== file.url)
          }
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error(error)
        },
      })
  }

// 4 Method to retrieve the fiel we've saved
  private async _getFilePath(fileName: string, blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
    const name = fileName

    try {
      // 5. Save the file locally
      return await this._saveBlobFile(blob, name)
    } catch {
      // 6. In case the file did already exists -> we retrieve it
      await Filesystem.getUri({
        path: name,
        directory: Directory.Cache,
      })
        .then((savedFile) => {
          return savedFile.uri
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
          throw new Error('Cannot save/open the file')
        })
    }
  }

// 5. Save the file locally
  private _saveBlobFile(blob: Blob, fileName: string) {
    return write_blob({
      path: fileName,
      directory: Directory.Cache,
      blob: blob,
    })
  }

// 7. Open the file
  private async _openFileWithType(filePath: string, fileType: string) {
    const fileOpenerOptions: FileOpenerOptions = {
      filePath: filePath,
      contentType: fileType,
    }

    await FileOpener.open(fileOpenerOptions)
      .then(() => {
        // 'File is opened'
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

//  Bonus: Localhost:4200. A little more code, to make it work even while testing on your laptop ;)
  public async openFile(file: CustomFile) {
    if (!file?.url) return

    try {
      this._downloadAndOpenFiles(file)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      Browser.open({ url: file.path })
    }
  }
```

### Bonus: FileSystem

The fileSystem is heavily used for this code, here are some small helps to guid you

1. [How to download](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem)
2. Don't forget to ask for permission ;)

```js
  getFilesystemAccess(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const status = await Filesystem.checkPermissions()
      const state = status.publicStorage

      if (state === 'granted') {
        return resolve(true)
      } else if (state === 'denied') {
        // You make want to redirect to the main app settings.
      } else {
        Filesystem.requestPermissions()
      }
      return resolve(false)
    })
  }
```

*Cheers*

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped alot. I found out how to use downloadFile() Api and created my own solution. I posted it as answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

**For those who want to download a blob file without having to host it in a URL on the server**

As stated in the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem), the "data" attribute of FileSystem.writeFile cannot receive blobs in native versions, working only for the web. An alternative would be to send the url parameter instead of data, like the previous solution

To make the blob data downloadable with FileSystem you will need to convert it to base64:

```
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file_blob)

reader.onloadend = function () {
    var base64data = reader.result
    Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: 'sample.pdf',
        data: base64data,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
    }).then((res) => {
        // here you can use openFileWithType from previous answer
        _this._openFileWithType(res.path, file_type)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I could fix it by adding the `recursive` parameter as true, and missing headers to proper auth. Hope this helps ;)

> NOTE: I am using just Capacitor as a wrapper of a web app.