# Capacitor FileSystem Android 13 storage permission for writeFile in Directory.Documents

Tags: android, angular, android-permissions, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

While using writeFile() in Capacitor/FileSystem in Android 13 error shows denied permission

These are the permissions I use:

Below is the code i use:

```
let permission = await Filesystem.requestPermissions();
if (permission.publicStorage == "granted") {
  let apiData = data?.split(',')[1];
  await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: `Appname/Filename.pdf`,
    data: apiData,
    directory: Directory.Documents,
    recursive: true
  });
}
```

This Works fine upto Android API level 30
For API level 33
Work around is given in the comments, still direct saving in documents directory is denied in capacitor 4.8.0

Comment: An app does not need any permission to create files in public Documents directory on Android 13+ devices. It comes by default.

Comment: But I am unable to create files in Documents path on Android 13, Even tried by removing all permissions, It returns no permissions in AndroidManifest
These are the permisisons i use
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="33"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MediaStore.createWriteRequest()"/>

Comment: You should not check for permissions. So remove `if (permission.publicStorage == "granted")`.

Comment: If I remove the condition it tries to create file and returns errors as user permission denied unable to create file

Comment: I found a work around for this functionality, Instead of storing the downloaded file directly in Documents Directory. I stored it in the **App Cache** folder and opened it via another capacitor package **capacitor-community/file-opener**, which further gives the user the ability to store the files in Documents Directory if required,  [Link for complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020808/capacitor-download-and-open-file-from-api)