# Download blob with ionic on Android/ios

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an application written with ionic/Angular. In my application I have to download an Excel file.

My server return json with the data in base64, file's name and mimetype. On ionic, I download the file like this :

```
return http.post(url, json, {headers : headers}).pipe(
      tap(async data => {

        var blob;
        

          data['data'] = atob(data['data'])
          const ia = new Uint8Array(data['data'].length)
          for (let i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++)
              ia[i] = data['data'].charCodeAt(i)
          var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: data['type'] })
        

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        a.href = url;
        a.download = data['fileName'];
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function(){ window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }, 30000);
      }),
    );
```

It works well on my computer, but it doesn't work on Android and iOS. On iOS I have this error :

> Failed to open URL
> blob:capacitor://localhost/cdb2a66c-5d46-48c7-ba16-ed83784cd8ed: Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_LSLine=277, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient
> openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}

Anyone can help me ? It looks like a limitation on iOS/Android. Is there a different solution to download the file ?

Answer (score 0):

`capacitor/Filesystem` and `capacitor-community/file-opener` packages used together will work for your requirement in this scenario, if the platform is mobile, you can convert the blob to `datauristring` or `base64` and use the accepted answer in this link ([Capacitor download and open file from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020808/capacitor-download-and-open-file-from-api)), you can use the path `Directory.Cache` to save the file instead of `Directory.Documents` so that you can download and open the file in  any system default apps