# create data url from fetched image

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64, data-uri

TL;DR

I'm trying to `fetch` and image, convert it to base64, and put the *data url* into an `img`'s `src` attribute, but it's not working:

```js
async function ajax(id) {
  const tag = document.getElementById(id);
  const path = tag.getAttribute("data-src");
  const response = await fetch(path);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const base64 = window.btoa(blob);
  const content = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`;
  tag.setAttribute("src", content);
}
```

The details, as well as some other methods, which *do* work follow.

---

I have been experimenting with different ways to lazy load:

```sh
$ mkdir lazy
$ cd lazy
$ wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg # any other example image
```

now create a file called `index.html` with this in it:

```html
<script>
  // this works
  function setAttribute(id) {
    const tag = document.getElementById(id);
    const path = tag.getAttribute("data-src");
    tag.setAttribute("src", path);
  }

  // this doesn't work for some reason
  async function ajax(id) {
    const tag = document.getElementById(id);
    const path = tag.getAttribute("data-src");
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const base64 = window.btoa(blob);
    const content = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`;
    tag.setAttribute("src", content);
  }

  // this works too
  async function works(id) {
    const tag = document.getElementById(id);
    const path = tag.getAttribute("data-src");
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const content = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    tag.setAttribute("src", content);
  }

</script>
<a href="javascript: setAttribute('example');">set attribute</a><br />
<a href="javascript: ajax('example');">data url</a><br />
<a href="javascript: works('example');">object url</a><br />
<img id="example" data-src="Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg"></img><br />
```

and start a server in that folder:

```sh
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer # or whichever local webserver
```

and then when I look at it in chrome I get this:

[image]

The first and third links both work:

[image]

However, the middle link does not:

[image]

Here is what the three links do to the tag respectively:

works:

```html
<img id="example" data-src="Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg" src="Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg">
```

does not work:

```html
<img id="example" data-src="Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,W29iamVjdCBCbG9iXQ==">
```

works:

```html
<img id="example" data-src="Lone_Ranger_and_Silver_1956.jpg" src="blob:http://localhost:8000/736a9e18-c30d-4e39-ac2e-b5246105c178">
```

That data url in the non working example also looks too short.  So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @dolpsdw.  `window.btoa` doesn't do what I thought it would.  If anybody is trying to do the same thing, instructions for reading a blob into a data url are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/5203563

I have created this wrapper that fits right into my program as follows:

(it even adds in the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part for you and works out the mime type from the blob)

```js
  function readBlob(b) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function() {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };

      // TODO: hook up reject to reader.onerror somehow and try it

      reader.readAsDataURL(b);
    });
  }

  async function ajax(id) {
    const tag = document.getElementById(id);
    const path = tag.getAttribute("data-src");
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    // const base64 = window.btoa(blob);
    // const content = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`;
    const content = await readBlob(blob);
    tag.setAttribute("src", content);
  }
```

this gives me the much longer data url that I expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you have the inmemory blob
Just generate a url for that blob

`var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)`

Then create a new IMG with JavaScript and invoke [decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method

```html
const img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.decode()
.then(() => {
  document.body.appendChild(img);
})
.catch((encodingError) => {
  // Do something with the error.
})
```

Maybe you want also to revoke URL after load with

`URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)`

---

About why the [window.btoa](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) does not work, its because is for string to base64 only.

Read about blob to base64 conversión [here](https://javascript.info/blob#blob-to-base64).
But is a more elegant solution createObjectURL.

Comment: I think this is the same as what I already put for my 3rd example, but I am wondering how to make the data url work (my second example)

Comment: Seems like the [btoa](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) only encode string to base64.

To encode a blob to base64 checkout [FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64).

Hoever i think is more optime to not process the img to extract the base64 and then make the browser to re-decode base64 and then decode the image.

Instead just use the createUrl.