# displaying a blob image in html page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following a **photo** field in a mysql table and I need to display it in an html page. The value of this field is something like: *0xFFD8FFE1127645786966000049492A00080000000C0000010300...*

I have tried the following to display it in a datatable:

```
columns: [
  {data: 'card_id', name: 'card_id'},
  {data: 'card_number', name: 'card_number'},
  {data: 'name_dr', name: 'name_dr'},
  {data: 'fname_dr', name: 'fname_dr'},
  {data: 'position_dr', name: 'position_dr'},
  {data: 'dept_dr', name: 'dept_dr'},
  {data: 'employee_code', name: 'employee_code'},
  {data: 'photo', name: 'photo'},
],
columnDefs: [
{ targets: 7,
  render: function(data) {
    //var img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+base64_encode(data);
    var img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+btoa(data);
    //const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(img);

    return '<img src="'+img+'">'
  }
}
```

But it does not work and I get an invalid image URL in console.
Please help me out!

Update:

Since base64_encode() is a php funciton, I use btoa() but I get only an image icon and not the real image.

Answer (score 1):

You need the FileReader in order to convert the blob to bas64.

See: [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64#answer-18650249)