# How to upload image with shopify Polaris DropZone component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I'm using Polaris to develop an app for Shopify and need to upload an image using [DropZone component](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/actions/drop-zone), but I can't find how to get base64 file.
Based on the document, in onDrop event,

I can get images files:
[image]

and also I can convert it to blob with this code:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0])
```

then I want to convert the file to base64, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polaris DropZone component works as an HTML file input, so there aren't any major differences between input and DropZone except UI and design. it returns a [file object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and you should load it as loading an image like this:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
```

now you can access to the blob and must [convert this blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64):

```
reader.onload = function () {
  var base64data = reader.result
}
```