# Sharepoint Framework: How to create an <img> tag containing MSGraph photo/$value response BLOB

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm creating a Sharepoint Application (using Shrepoint Framework) and I'm not being able to retrieve the Phto BLOB returned when calling MSGraph "/me/photo/$value" api. I don't know how to convert the BLOB into a Base64 string. I have made many attempts, I'm writing one to explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

`this.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        client.api('/me/photo/$value').get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
          const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(rawResponse.body);
          document.getElementById("myPhoto").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
        });
      });`

This code fails because creteObjectURL has been deprecated. 
The MSGraph call works, but I can't process the response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) accepts blob as its parameter. And you can get blob response like below:

```
client.api('/me/photo/$value').responseType('blob').
```

The bloburl will be like:

```
blob:https://xxxx-app34cc3db2636944a5b0b3abea9a6ae5b9.sharepoint.com/e007d253-f911-4722-86a8-ecdd77864696
```

Also you can convert blob to base64 via [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL):
[Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)

Besides, you can also make use of pnpjs to access ms graph, it could directly return blob data:
[Current User](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/users/#current-user)

Best Regards,
Baker Kong