# Blob to base64 ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, blob

I'm trying to encode a blob audio file to base64 in ReactJS , but the following code is producing an error:

```
submit(blob) {
        console.log("BLOB", blob)
        // var blob = new Blob([blob])
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            var base64data = reader.result;
            console.log(base64data);
        }
```

I have tried every [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64/42038379) but I am still getting the error 
**TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**

BLOB: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(blob.blob);
```

Looks like you need to go one more step to access the actual blob