# Weird characters within the response of file

Tags: json, file-upload, response

I'm working with an API for uploading a user image, the uploading process is quite simple, just choose the file from the user's device and send it as it is in a FormData (File, Binary).

But, when it comes for downloading this file from the storage, the response is really wired for me and containing some characters that because of it I can't indicate if that is a problem from the back-end handling or it's an invalid file or it's a regular formula that I didn't deal with it before.

my question is what should this data represent? And how to convert it to a file that a user can download?

here is a screenshot of it.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyxmd.png)

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: ok, and what language did you use to get data from backend?

Comment: I would love that, it would help me a lot in debugging but, I don't have the back-end code. and the screenshot is just the response of the api

Comment: I don't know how to help you because you don't give information like language or etc. But now I assume you use postman to call API. 

according to screenshot that you give, I only can tell you, response have raw response with type `IHDR` and backend give response `JSON` type.

Comment: This is what an PNG is going to look like when you display the file's contents as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with many cases, the problem was that I didn't define the *content-type* within the request headers

```
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'blob'
}
```

notice that this type of data is a regular Blob file.

- for downloading it, review this question [JavaScript blob filename
  without link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/13649647)
- for converting it to a base64 string, review this question [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/13649647)