# How to access data from ReadableStream response?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, fetch

I made an API call to an endpoint and it returns this:

[image]

```
const test = () => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

How can I obtain the ReadableStream in a Base64 format? This is returning a png file.

Comment: have you tried reading the `fetch` documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/13608595) answer, you can get the blob and convert it to base64.

```
const test = () => {
    fetch(endpoint)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.blob();
      })
      .then((blob)=>{
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
          reader.onloadend = function() {
              var base64data = reader.result;                
              console.log(base64data);
          }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

[MDN on `.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)