# FileReader - fetch image and converti into base64

Tags: javascript, fetch, filereader

I'm trying to fetch and convert into blob/base64 an image from an online resource but the code I'm using seems not working

```
fetch('https://example.com/image.jpg')
.then( res => res.blob() )
.then( data => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloaded = () => {
      console.log(reader.readAsDataURL(data))    
    }     
})
```

what's wrong with it and what I need to change to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)

This issue was solved already ;)