# how to convert blob to arraybuffer or string to blob

Tags: java, binary, blob

Imagine I have a file with this data:

```
lastModified: 1543877513859
lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 04 2018 02:21:53 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time) {}
name: "ali.jpg"
objectURL: SafeUrlImpl
changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "blob:http://localhost:4200/b45412e9-69ad-433f-b24d-b3833d705da4"
__proto__: SafeValueImpl
size: 16196
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

So I want to get the binary data of this image. I read some info of how to get the content of image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64).  so I try to get the binary data with this:

```
const expecteadBinaryData= file.objectURL.
        changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity.arrayBuffer();
        reader.onload = (e) => e.target.result;
        const expecteadBinaryData2 =reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob
          ([file.objectURL.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity]));
```

So I expect the result of `expecteadBinaryData` or `expecteadBinaryData2` be a binary, but I get undefined. How should I get this?

Comment: From my case, convert string to blob just do something like this: `new Blob(["MyExampleString"], { type: 'text/plain' })`

Comment: dear @TitusSutioFanpula what should I replace instead of "MyExampleString" ? which field of file?

Comment: The `string` you want to convert to `blob`. Before you do that things, make sure your `string` is not `null` or `undefined`.