# how to save image as a blob in local storage or session storage in javascript or react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

i am tring

```
 const [image, setImage] = useState('');
 useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('image', JSON.stringify(image));

    let localImage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('image'));
    console.log(localImage);
    console.log(image);
  }, [image]);

  <input type="file" onChange={() => setImage(e.target.files[0])} 
    accept="image/*" />;
```

variable `localImage` gives me image file but not a **blob** file

I want a **blob** for send to server

Comment: image is a state (real image file)

Comment: Is there any reason you are storing image in localStorage?

Comment: when i send localImage to server its giving me [object, object] not an original image
i am trying to send this image to server after refreshing tha page .

Comment: So your use case is to upload user selected image after page refresh. For this convert the image to base64 and store in localStorage. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page) will give some info

Comment: how to convert base64 to image

Comment: That depends on what is your backend. In node check this [Convert a Base64 data into an Image in Node.js](https://dev.to/dnature/convert-a-base64-data-into-an-image-in-node-js-3f88). If you want to show this in browser you can use the base64 data to create a data url and assign this to `src` of the img tag

Comment: i went to convert in front end if possible.
is this possible ?