# send an excel file as a blob in the post api

Tags: reactjs, post, blob

I want to use the post API to send an excel file as a blob file. Below is my code.

```
const Csvsubmit = (event) => {
    console.log("csv", excelFile);
    setLoadingcsv(true);

    const requestOption = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        file_upload: excelFile,
        created_by: user.id,
      }),
    };

    const response = fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + subdomain + "/staff/csvupload/",
      requestOption
    ).then(
      (res) => {
        if (res.status === 201) {
          res.json().then((json) => {
            setLoadingcsv(false);
            console.log(json);
            setopenid(0);
          });
        } else if (res.status === 406) {
          console.log("file format is not supported");
          setLoadingcsv(false);
        } else {
          setLoadingcsv(false);

          res.json().then((json) => {
            setLoadingcsv(false);
          });
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    console.log("Answer", requestOption.body);
  };
```

The "csv" cansole blob data is printed, but the body is empty.how to send this file(.xls,.xslx,.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json doesn't support binary data.
You need to encode the blob into something else, (base64 is recomended),
Good Luck!

See also this answer,

[Convert blob to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64)