# How to read data from a blob?

Tags: javascript, blob, webrtc, webm

Is there a way to read data from a blob that is used by a `<video>` tag?

E.g. on youtube it looks like this:

```
<video autoplay
   src="blob:https%3A//ecample.com/92e970b0-7cde-47f9-bdea-9347381d28a3">
</video>
```

Can I access this data by known blob url?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url answer? not sure if this works on all browsers

Comment: Yes I tried, but somehow it doesn't work with blob url that is used for video.

Comment: have you tried FileReader?