# Open a file with blob URL

Tags: javascript, image, file, blob

I searched for a while but I didn't find anything. (Maybe bad keywork or I don't know)

I use a javascript text editor plugin (tinyMCE).
In this plugin, I can past a picture from my clipboard, and it's automatically created in an HTML Element.
The source of the  element is a path URL (a string) with blob format (blob:http://something.com)

I want to access with a File object (in variable) to this image (for personnal reason, not realy important)

But I didn't find any constructor of File or Blob whith String parameter, or any sample of code.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: doesn't help me.
`Parameter : array is an Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, `DOMString objects, or a mix of any of such objects, that will be put inside `the Blob. `DOMStrings are encoded as UTF-8.
I have String src.

Comment: You said you "didn't find any constructor of File or Blob or any sample of code". That link shows the constructor of Blob, and a sample of code...

Comment: I have explain that I only have a string. Implied a constructor with a String parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a file or blob from an object URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url)