# Read data from blob url

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob, filereader, arraybuffer

I've preload a mp4 video with xhr and save it to a blob url

```
xhr.responseType = 'blob'
// xhr send and get response
var url = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
player.src(url);
// It's worked, it's playable and seekable.
//url = blob url string
```

Now I need to process that video so I need to get data back as arrayBuffer, how to get data (blob object) back when you have blob url
blob:http://domain/9d0d26c3-b7ba-4302-9186-d23c6ad53bd5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some research because I'm also interessted in this question and I think the only possibility is do to a XHR request. I think it was already disscussed here: [How to get a file or blob from an object URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url)

If you have a blob you can convert it with `FileReader` to a `ArrayBuffer`. But maybe also the following could work:

```
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```