# download file in react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, download

i have an Restful API i created using Laravel, this API like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file/pdf/{id}
```

and this is my code for download:

```
public function pdfDownload($id){
       $pdf = Cv::findOrfail($id);
       return Storage::download('public/pdf/'.$pdf->pdf);
    }
```

it is worked in postman, and also in browser, it is directly download the file,
but with react.js, it is not work, this my code in react:

```
pdfDownload = (id) => {
        fetch(' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file/pdf/' + id, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            }
        }).then((res) => res.json());
    };
```

and i call this function in button like this :

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.pdfDownload(data.id)}>
                                            Download
                                        </Button>
```

the id is corrected, i am ensure from this, my question is how can i download file when click this button.. Thans...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XHR calls can not trigger file download, the way browser handles it. You will have to mimic a file download using javascript code yourself, using something like below:

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Or use File Saver package, if you don't mind an extra dependency.

[FileSaver Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Comment: Thank you, it is seem good, but how can i use
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
how can i pass my file from API instead of (file.pdf)?

Comment: Please follow that GIST. Api result blob should be used to create a Blob. I just gave an example of file.pdf in download attribute, you can use any file name you want as per your file type.

Comment: @OsamaMohammed you can change the file name and the extension type as per your need. For example, if the API is returning you a file that has an extension of '.xlsx', you have to change the extension and file name accordingly. For example:

link.setAttribute('download', 'my_excel_file.xlsx');

Comment: Is there any way to download a file without loading it into the browser?@AjayK