# button to download a file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a personal portfolio, I am trying to make a button that if you click it should download a Resume.

code

```
<form method="get" action="fileName">
        <button class="myButton" type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

let the user download the file.

I am working in REACTJS, create-react-app

Comment: where is this file stored?

Comment: I have the file in my components folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by this way

```
<a href="./yourfile.pdf" download>Download CV</a>
```

Comment: Actually it does the download but it says the Failed - No file.

Comment: you have to give the right path: for example if your file in public folder "/filePath.pdf"

Comment: it is in my components folder which my main.js file is too. so what I have is "./document.pdf"

Comment: try to move the file to public folder and the path will be "/document.pdf"

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez if it is downloading, but shows an error like "Failed to load PDF document" when trying to open the pdf, it may be that you are using a *relative* path on your href and the final path it generates does not match the one were you have stored your file. Try using an absolute path on href. It should start with a slash /

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#readme) to achieve this goal:

Install the npm package: `npm install file-saver --save`

```
const saveFile = () => {
fileSaver.saveAs(
  process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL + "/resources/cv.pdf",
  "MyCV.pdf"
);
```

};

```
<button className="cv" onClick={saveFile}>
    Download File
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem, and here is the solution I make use of now:

#### Steps

3 steps:

1. **Make use of file saver in project**: [npmjs/package/file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) (`npm install file-saver` or something)
2. **Place the file in your project** You say it's in the components folder. Well, chances are if you've got web-pack it's going to try and minify it.(someone please pinpoint what webpack would do with an asset file in components folder), and so I don't think it's what you'd want. So, I suggest to place the asset into the `public` folder, under a `resource` or an `asset` name. Webpack doesn't touch the `public` folder and `index.html` and your resources get copied over in production build as is, where you may refer them as shown in next step.
3. **Refer to the file in your project** Sample code:

   ```js
   import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
   FileSaver.saveAs(
       process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/resource/file.anyType",
       "fileNameYouWishCustomerToDownLoadAs.anyType");
   ```

#### Source

- [Create-React-App.dev | Using the public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)
- [Github | File saver documentation](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#readme)

#### Appendix

- I also try `Link` component of `react-router` [react-router-docs/Link](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html). The zip file would download, and somehow would unzip properly. Generally, links have blue color, to inherit parent color scheme, simply add a prop like: `style={color: inherit}` or simply assign a class of your CSS library like `button button-primary` or something if you're Bootstrappin'
- Other sage questions it's closely related to:

  - [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js)
  - [download file in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906497/download-file-in-react)
  - [how to download file in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694881/how-to-download-file-in-react-js/50695407)
  - [button to download a file in reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083785/button-to-download-a-file-in-reactjs)
  - [download sample file in public folder (react)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374561/download-sample-file-in-public-folder-react)

Not useful, still good answers here:

- [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)
- [When will an <a> tag not inherit color attribute of parent tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144931/when-will-an-a-tag-not-inherit-color-attribute-of-parent-tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
import MyPDF from '../path/to/file.pdf';    
<a href={myPDF} download="My_File.pdf"> Download Here </a>
```

Replace with your stuff