# download sample file in public folder (react)

Tags: reactjs, download, xlsx

I want to put a sample xlsx file in my public folder (react project) and others can download this file.

```
<Button><link rel="chargeSample" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/chargeSample.xlsx"></link></Button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  tag defines a link between a document and an external resource.
To let download funcionality on your website you should change link tag

```
import chargeSample from './public/chargeSample.xlsx';

<Button><a href={chargeSample} download="your file name">Download</a></Button>
```

Comment: i am stuck at this. downloading this way works locally, but when deployed to public, it fails and instead downloads just an empty corrupted file. Any ideas on that ?

Comment: The corners of the button tag wont click to download. Maybe better to incase the button inside the a tag

Answer (score 3):

If you are using creat react app, you can pass public path into your components at build time by using

```
process.env.PUBLIC_URL
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we have to think about where you store the file, thinking about what react is going to do in build time. In develop, you can't trust 100% that the paths you use are going to be the same after building the app.
[Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) in the create react app doc there is some info about when to use the public folder and how to use it.

To download a file stored in the public folder, you have to reference it with the PUBLIC_URL. There are two ways of doing this:

**Reference a file from inside the public folder**
You will have to use de `%PUBLIC_URL%` as you mentioned.
For example, if you want to use a fav icon in the main HTML file, you have to add the icon in the public folder and then in the `index.html` you will reference this file with the `%PUBLIC_URL%` prefix.

```
// public/index.html
// ...other stuff
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
// ...
```

In build time, React will replace this hash with the path to that folder

**Reference a file in the src folder**
To reference a file from inside the src folder, you have to access the public folder URL. React saves this path in an environment variable. To be able to use that file you have to use the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` path.
To download a file from the public folder, you can access it like this:

```
<a
  href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/my-file.txt"}
  download={"file-name-to-use.txt"}
>
    Download file
</a>
```

When clicking the anchor tag it will try to download the file stored in `/public` with the name `my-file.txt` and it will use as a placeholder name for that file the one specified in the `download` property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Lucas gave the best answer. Just to add since I was looking for a way to programmatically create a link element (let's say when you received a new excel file from an API call in runtime/deployment) then you can do something as follows:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', `${Date.now()}.xlsx`); //set the attribute of the <a> link tag to be downloadable when clicked and name the sheet based on the date and time right now.
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click(); //programmatically click the link so the user doesn't have to
document.body.removeChild(link);
URL.revokeObjectURL(url); //important for optimization and preventing memory leak even though link element has already been removed.
```

Credits to top answers here:

[How to download files using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938718/how-to-download-files-using-axios?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to download excel in response from api react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890870/how-to-download-excel-in-response-from-api-react-js)